# 'Diablo 3 Acts' rule change—everyone gets a t-shirt!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, diablo-3

We have decided to remove the prize limit for Act 1 and give away an unlimited number of t-shirts. What this means is now everyone who completes any Act wins a prize! The 25% rule for Acts 2, 3, and 4 will remain in place, but if your name is not selected from one of those drawings, you'll still get one of those awesome Diablo/Gaming.SE t-shirts that Jin designed.

[image: Gaming.SE Diablo 3 t-shirt]

The Rules on diablo3acts.com will be updated shortly to reflect this change. In the meantime, keep doing what you're doing!

**[Edit]**: These t-shirts are in such high demand that we've decided to give them to everyone who completes any Act! What this means is no matter which Acts you complete, you'll get a t-shirt. If you complete Acts 2, 3, or 4, you'll be entered into the raffle for another prize, and you'll get a shirt regardless of whether you're selected.

Comment: This is awesome news.  Thanks Lauren (and the rest of the SE team)!

Comment: @Lauren Just to understand: "if your name is not selected from one of those drawings, you'll still get one of those awesome Diablo/Gaming.SE t-shirts that Jin designed" means that who gets one of the other prizes doesn't get a shirt?

Comment: @Kappei: From my reading of the original rules, there was always a stipulation of one prize (of the winners choice) in the event they won more than one draw, so I would say that yes, that is exactly right. I would love to be proven wrong though.

Comment: @Kappei you know what, let's just give t-shirts to everyone :-) Will update rules shortly.

Comment: Just completed Act 1, very happy to be getting one of these!

Comment: @Lauren that makes everyone eligible to win three prices, no? T-shirt + one prize from Acts 2-4 + something from the gems.It's also confusing that there are two footnotes with an asterisk.

Comment: @Wieland yes, this makes it possible to win 3 prizes total, 2 from the Acts.

Comment: do people getting the gems also qualify for tshirts? or does it just apply to the acts?

Comment: @corroded you had to qualify for Act 1 to get the t-shirt