# How do we know if we won something from the diablo 3 contest?

Tags: support, site-promotion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Diablo 3 Prize Winners!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4795/diablo-3-prize-winners)

How do we know? Do we get an email or a SE message or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If past contests are any indication, you will get an email notification and the contest meta thread will be updated to include the winners.

Don't expect this to happen for a few days, as CHAOS is very busy people. But don't worry, it *is* going to happen!

Answer (score 1):

As ['Diablo 3 Acts' rule change—everyone gets a t-shirt!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4704/diablo-3-acts-rule-changeeveryone-gets-a-t-shirt) notes, everyone who made Act I gets a T-Shirt so most will be contacted anyway.  I presume they'll notify winners at the same time.