# Diablo 3 Prize Winners!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

**Update**: Most of the prizes have been shipped by now. The t-shirts are taking a little longer because we had to wait to have them made until we got everyone's sizes. Just talked to our warehouse and they told me the shirts would ship early next week. Sorry about that! But they're worth the wait, I promise!

---

**Emails asking for your mailing address and prize choice (if applicable) have been sent.** If you won a t-shirt or a prize from the Gems, the email includes a form that must be filled out in order for me to send you your prize. **Please fill the form out by 5 pm EST on Tuesday June 12th so that I can place the orders**. If your order is not in by then, unfortunately you won't be able to claim your prize.

If you won a prize from Acts 2, 3, or 4 I will have your mailing address from the t-shirt form I sent you.

Thanks everyone!

---

There are a bunch of you, get ready!

As you know, everyone who completed Act 1 will win a t-shirt. Winners for Acts 2-4 and the Gems are below!

**Prize winners for Act 2:** ([Diablo 3 Gaming Mouse](http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/MissionPromo/Diablo3/img/prize-mouse.jpg))

- Ayckoster
- Beofett
- Bruce Connor
- dlanod
- Fredy31
- Ian Pugsley
- Kexlox
- Klokworkk
- Oak
- Rapida
- Resorath
- Spugsley

**Prize winners for Act 3:** ([Diablo 3 Headset](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005L38SGY))

- agent86
- bwarner
- LessPop_MoreFizz
- Mr. November
- Nick T

**Prize winners for Act 4:** ([a new monitor](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_p_36_5?bbn=1292115011&qid=1336675554&rh=n:172282,n:!493964,n:541966,n:1292115011&rnid=386442011&low-price=&high-price=250&x=13&y=13)*)

- heishe
- Rachel

**Prize winners for the Gems:** (a new graphics card from [amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/)*)

- Anders
- BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft
- Bruce Connor
- Brysonic
- Ender
- Fredy31
- Guesswho
- He Hui
- Hyppy
- jblaske
- Kappei
- Michael Malura
- Michel Ayres
- Mikle
- Pent
- pinouchon
- Rangoric
- Resorath
- SAGExSDX
- SBoss
- sjohnston
- skolima
- StrixVaria
- ThiefMaster
- Travis J

* See details on http://diablo3acts.com/

Winners will be contacted via email. Congrats, and thanks to everyone who participated! I think Sanctuary will survive another day...

Comment: Aww man, I was eligible for everything except Act IV, just didn't luck out. :( I still get a T-Shirt though! :) Thanks for hosting a great contest SE!

Comment: Awesome! Now I can wipe in Inferno on two monitors :-)

Comment: I'm so excited, I'm finally going to get myself an HD monitor ^_^

Comment: \*ctrl+f dpatchery\* 1 match found!!! \*sees username at top of screen\* \*cries\*. Anyway, congrats to all the winners!

Comment: So, do we still get a t-shirt if we won one of the other Act prizes?  I'm honestly way more excited about the shirt :)

Comment: WOO-HOO!!! Awesome!!! Thanks guys, thank you very much! And also thanks for the great t-shirt! And congratulations to all the others!

Comment: Awesome! I didn't win anything, but I am eligible for the t-shirt, and I am sure glad this site existed for all the Diablo questions! Thanks guys

Comment: @Kexlox yes, everyone who completed Act 1 gets a prize, regardless of whether you won a prize from another Act :-)

Comment: @Lauren awesome, I know what I'm wearing to GenCon this year! :)

Comment: Congrats to all the winners, I didn't get lucky with Act 2 drawing ... but the contest was a lot of fun, I only started participating to get rep up to 50 and the level of interest on D3 Q&A really made it easy to be engaged in the discussions.

Comment: congrats to all winners!

Comment: Gratz to the winners! Didn't win anything but I'm new to the site and the T-shirt looks awesome ;)

Comment: congrats! hope we see more of these contests -*drool*-

Comment: yesssssss. A new headset to compliment my new rig :).

Comment: Gem winners: check out Tom's Hardware's [Best Graphics Cards For The Money: May 2012](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/gaming-graphics-card-review,3107.html) article.  Around $250: GeForce GTX 560 Ti (~$230), or Radeon HD 7850 (~$260, but prices can vary a little)

Comment: Funnily enough I've been looking at buying a mouse for a few months but never gotten my act together.  Serendipity, you and your cunning ways...

Comment: I feel bad for Raven Dreamer...first one done, and he got completely shafted.  Luck of the draw I guess.

Comment: Have the emails been sent? I completed Act I, but haven't received any email yet. Just checking :)

Comment: No, I'm sorting through everyone right now. You should get something very soon.

Comment: I did not receive a t-shirt form to fill out, however I did receive an email from you about winning. Did the form not get sent to users who won prizes?

Comment: Conversely, I got a t-shirt email and no prize email. I assume the emails simply aren't done being sent out.

Comment: Hi Lauren, I did not receive a shirt e-mail (or an Act prize e-mail). I did get a e-mail asking about which graphics card I wanted, which I assume can be recycled for the Act prize, but no e-mail about the tshirt (which I assume you need a size for).

Comment: @Resorath do me a favor and check your email again? I just sent another batch of t-shirt emails so you should have it now. Re: the Act prize, you won Act 2, which is the Gaming mouse, and I'll have your email from the t-shirt form, so don't need any further info on that.

Comment: @Mr.November see my edit above - people who won prizes for Acts 2 and 3 won't get a separate email since I'll have your address from the tshirt email.

Comment: @Rachel I just sent another batch of tshirt emails, you should have it now. Thanks!

Comment: @Lauren I received the 2nd email, thank you :)

Comment: @Lauren Thanks, I got the second e-mail.

Comment: Always the unlucky one haha...

Comment: When will these be sent out and what sort of shipping will be used? Sorry to sound impatient, but I generally try and plan so I'm at home when a package arrives.

Comment: @Mr.November the tshirts will be shipped from our warehouse. I'm waiting until I receive all the orders to place them. When I do I'll post an ETA here.

Comment: I received my monitor. That was fast!

Comment: I never received a prize email, only a t-shirt email.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz that's because you already sent your address for the t-shirt. Since you don't have to choose your prize, there's no need for a second email.

Comment: Derp. Missed the edit!

Comment: @Lauren: I haven't received a t-shirt email

Comment: have the prizes shipped yet?

Comment: @Mr.November I believe things are to be shipped tomorrow.

Comment: @Klokworkk hooray :D

Comment: My mouse arrived today, so things are definitely shipping :)

Comment: Got my mouse today, as well.  Thanks again for a great promotion!

Comment: @Lauren Will i get my T shirt in South Africa? :D

Comment: Graphics card just arrived :)

Comment: @Josefvz we place all the t-shirt orders through our warehouse, if there are any problems with shipping they'll let us know.

Comment: @Lauren okay Awesome TY :D

Comment: So...how exactly did the gems work, again? The prize page says "Each Gem you unlock gets you one entry into a drawing for prizes. The number of names drawn will be equal to 25% of the total number entries [sic]"...just the number of perfect star topazes listed on the contest page would have generated 44 prizes, and no prize cap was specified for the gem contest under the asterisk. Not that I expect or want the prize, or know how I'd integrate 1.25 video cards into my laptop.

Comment: Actually, there was a prize cap specified: "* 25% of the total number of entries will be chosen from the Gem drawing, up to 25." I'm sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: How can I tell whether my address information was submitted properly? I don't really trust a form made with Google spreadsheet.

Comment: Or how long should we expect to wait before we contact you and find out if something went wrong?

Comment: If you typed your information into the Google spreadsheet correctly, then we received it. If something is returned as undeliverable or there is a problem with your address, I will contact you. If you are in the US and don't receive your package within two weeks let me know. International orders may take significantly longer than that.

Comment: I got it!  ehehehehehehehe

Comment: Just received my video card in the mail :-). Huge thanks to @Lauren and the rest of the SE team!

Comment: @Lauren Sorry for being a pain. But i wantz my shirt! I want to show of the awesomness that is Arqade to all my geeks. Is there anyway I can track the Status of my order/shipment?

Comment: @Josefvz the shirts will ship next week. We had to wait to have them made until we got everyone's sizes, so they took a little longer than the other prizes. Glad you're excited to show it off to your friends though! Sorry to make you wait :-/

Comment: Sorry I don't have mad skillz in video editing :).

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LCaWVh9-LQ

Comment: While I'm a bit disappointed at the shirts' design, thanks a lot for the great initiative and organization :)  hope we'll get the chance to take part to more of these !  
(Also, I like the SE blue box - very classy !)

Comment: So yea... here we are in the end of July.... No shirt, no Info, no extra Arqade swagger for me... I'm so Sad... :(

Comment: @Josefvz all you're waiting on is the shirt right? I checked and you are included in the list of people the shirts were sent to. International shipping just takes a lot more time than shipping in the US.

Comment: @Lauren Yes. O yea, I forgot about the international shipping. Sorry.

Answer (score 14):

Random graphs (yay Google Docs charts)

Suggest more if you like.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Congrats to all the winners, although I didn't join you it was nice to see a big mix of new names on the list.

Comment: It's very nice to see how new/newish users were able to win stuff :)

Comment: Nice chart! Definitely interesting to see. Was hoping some newer people would be able to win from the Gems :-)