# What type of community events would you like to see?

Tags: discussion, community-event

When we asked for input in our [2019 Community Check-in](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13489/arqade-community-check-in-2019-a-call-for-input), one of the themes present in more than one answer was the desire to build a feeling of belonging to a community and encourage participation in asking and answering questions by using contests, events, tournaments and the like. Now we want to hear your suggestions on what kinds of events we should hold!

#### Events? What are those?

If you weren't here when the site was young, you might not know that Arqade used to have different kinds of events back in the day, such as:

- The [Promotional Grants](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2010/community-promotion-sponsorship-new-game-releases-for-community-members), buying games for users to ask and answer questions about.
- [Mass Effect 3 Missions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4132/mass-effect-3-missions-on-gaming-se), the [Answer Swarm](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/starcraft-2-heart-of-the-swarm-event), and [Diablo III Acts](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4795/diablo-3-prize-winners), sets of game-themed challenges to be completed on Arqade.
- [Game On!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-on), a series of events played by members of the community, and then uploaded to YouTube.
- [Movie Nights](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11441/so-you-want-to-attend-movie-night), in which users watched movies together.

The last two were organized entirely by Arqade users, with no external support from the Stack Exchange network. While more SE-sponsored events are not outside the realm of possibility, we’re thinking all our future events will be community-run, with no prizes beyond the friends we made along the way. The main goal of these events will be to bring the community together and perhaps motivate users to ask and answers questions about the featured games.

We're hoping to get a variety of suggestions, with a focus on events that can involve anyone in the community. For example, a tournament for a niche game might not receive much attention without enough players, or a Let's Play of slow-paced puzzle game might not be very entertaining to watch, even if very fun to play. Suggestions for both one-time events and recurrent series of events are welcome.

In the end, we are here because we enjoy gaming, so let’s game together.

Comment: How long is this question going to be open? Most answers (one exception) were posted between Nov 2 and Nov 5. I'd really look forward to experiencing community events, so I'd appreciate learning what the timeframe is for this inquiry.

Comment: @PausePause The question is going to stay open indefinitely. Some good ideas were posted and are being discussed, and should start once the final details are decided on.

Comment: When we have some events i suggest adding them to e.g. a Google calendar, so you can get a better overview over what events take place at which time.

Comment: I'm considering livestreaming the process of answering tricky questions. Should I make a meta post every time I do that or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 18):

How about a **Screenshot of the Week**?

I just noticed the *Photo of the Week* on [Photography SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/). I assume this will be easy to implement as it has already been integrated there.

While not really an event, it will help build "*a feeling of belonging to a community and encourage participation*".

A corresponding [Hall of Fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939) (similar to [the one Photo.SE](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708)) will leave a permanent record of the (top-voted) screenshots, and might inspire others to see creativity as part of gaming, and maybe to try their hand at games they are not familiar with.
It will also increase the visual appeal of the main page, and possibly make the Meta page - where the threads where we could cast votes would be found - more accessible to the more casual user.

---

Here's an example of an image hidden behind a spoiler tag:

> [image]

Comment: Cool idea. My only worry would be about spoilers

Comment: Do you think that would be a large problem? We could always make it a rule that a screenshot can't contain spoilers. I think it generally would be nothing to worry about.

Comment: Probably not a big problem, but I do know several games in which some screenshots i have would spoil a large portion of the story line.

Comment: What do you define as a spoiler though? What might be a spoiler to one person might not be to another.

Comment: I agree spoilers could be an issue.  I like this idea, but I think it needs to come with a disclaimer that you may get games spoiled if you browse the weekly thread.

Comment: Images can be hidden behind spoiler tags, if required. I'f gone ahead and added an example of this to the answer.

Comment: IIRC, it took a lot of work to get that working properly on photo.SE, and it's stuff that's all custom to the site.  Not sure if the devs would be willing to put in the effort for us.

Answer (score 12):

I know it's often overdone, but what are your thoughts on an Arqade Minecraft world? I don't think it falls into a community "event" category, but more like "The Bridge" hangout space. I'm confident many users on this site have not played the game in a while (such as myself) and would appreciate the opportunity to return to Minecraft and see the recent updates.

Update: A similar idea was implemented in Game-On! a few years ago. I think the game has changed enough that it could still be attempted again.

Comment: I think this could be fun.

Comment: There was an Arqade Minecraft server for quite some time after the death of "Game-On!"  A couple different modpacks were used over time.  It seemed rather successful, overall, even if it was propped up by a small handful of regulars.

Comment: Minecraft is always a good idea.

Comment: Quite a LOT has changed in the last couple of years, alone the "new" combat mechanics and tons of new blocks etc. are worth giving it another try.

Comment: @PausePause have you thought of anything specific regarding what kind of MC you would want on such a server? e.g. Pure Vanilla, FTB, Skyblock etc.?

Comment: I'm personally a fan of semi-vanilla Bukkit w/ Spigot style of server where there are protections against griefing and some features for convenience but the core Minecraft gameplay is the same.

Comment: Sadly, protection against griefing is a must have nowadays, there are just tto many trolls out there :(
But apart from some extra-commands to protect you stuff (e.g. /cprivate) i also usually play on a vanilla server with only griefing protection.

Answer (score 8):

I would like to take part in some Arqade tournaments for various different games. Personally I'm a big fan of Smash Bros., but there's plenty of games that support a competitive scene - pretty much any fighting game, League of Legends (could do 1v1), Age of Empires... heck, we could even do something like Minecraft Spleef or SkyWars.

Comment: Rainbow Six Siege would surely also count as competitive, you can even give people handicaps to balance / make the game more fun to fool around and / or create interesting challenges.

Answer (score 8):

A specific type of game that could be fun is the [Jackbox Party games](https://jackboxgames.com/).

These would work well because some allow higher player counts (8 players + an 'audience' with participation for some games).

Plus, they have a low barrier to entry, only requiring players to have access to a web browser (and some way of viewing the stream).

Comment: Even though it's not what first comes to mind when one thinks of "games", I really like this idea.

Comment: Yeah, plus it doesn't have the issue TTS has of requiring people to own the game (though we should also play TTS)

Comment: We do have a (community) discord.  I've found that the video latency for that is rather low, whereas something like Twitch could be too high for Jackbox games.

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to see weekly, monthly, or otherwise periodic gaming sessions for multiplayer games, with a focus on playing as a group rather than having one side against the other like in tournaments.

A multitude of games would be suitable for this, both PvE and PvP, such as:

- Warframe
- League of Legends
- Minecraft
- Monster Hunter
- Overwatch
- World of Warcraft
- etc

Note that I'm not suggesting to switch games played every session, just listing possible games that could be good to play in a group. Each game would have its own schedule.

Comment: Add TF2 and/or CS:GO to that list, being free the barrier to entry will be lower :)

Comment: @Robotnik Warframe and LoL are both ftp

Comment: WoW won't work well due to region restrictions and factions.

Answer (score 6):

This is more of an addition to other suggestions, really. For any event that would only involve a handful of users playing together, such as a tournament or any session of a co-op game, I would like to see the gameplay being streamed, so as to involve users who are either unable or unwilling to participate directly. This could be done from the perspective of a "spectator" or "commentator" for tournaments, or just one of the players' perspective for co-op games.

Comment: You could also - enough people given - give people handicaps / advantages ingame by voting in chat.

Answer (score 4):

Bringing back Movie Nights could be a good idea, I think. IIRC the reason we mostly stopped was due to us all being busy, but things seem to have calmed down a bit for a lot of us, so I think there might be interest in this again.

Rabb.it going down will cause some issues with regards to watching the movies together, but if we do decide to start up movie nights again I'm willing to look up (and if needed, set up) alternatives for us to use.

Comment: I ended up looking around for a Rabb.it alternative a few weeks ago for unrelated reasons and found a suitable one remarkably hard to come by.  A lot of them only supported Youtube, or had serious usability issues.  I always did enjoy the movie nights I was able to make it to, though.

Comment: @JohntheGreen I'm aware of a couple alternatives that'll do the job, I forgot their names though, I'll have to dig in my message.

Answer (score 4):

A **Monthly Answer Challenge** (or weekly, or Fortnitely, or bimonthly, ..):
a rep bonus for the best answer given to an old question.

Piggybacking on [Movies.SE's concept](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4613/monthly-answer-challenge-2020-solve-old-unanswered-questions), this will give users an extra boost to travel deep into the depths of our 'Arqives' and solve some of its many mysteries.

We can set the limit to what counts as an 'old question' to 3 months - similar to Movies.SE - but can also work our way forward from the oldest posts, by setting an initial limit of 5 years, and see how that goes.

It's constructive, accessible to all users, and will hopefully decrease the amount of unanswered questions (currently 6.360 questions remain unanswered or unupvoted [(out of 91.207 total = +/- 7%]).
And, as the answerers dust off their old jewel and keep cases in anticipation, it gives them a chance to grab a few screenshots for whenever [this topic](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15041/222022) will get its turn.

Comment: Arqives, that's brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

Rep Bonuses or Featured Tag about games that have been released recently or ones that we can choose on a weekly basis. This encourages people to use the site, play games to come up with good questions and answer them!

If we can't do bonus rep, something like a featured tag would be cool. Last week would have been a great opportunity for a "purple" outline on questions with a featured tag of "the-outer-worlds" to give users a push to ask questions and answer a specific tag. We could implement this for 10-year anniversaries of games, sold benchmarks and all kinds of milestones.

For example:

**Weekly Question Bonus Tag: Skyrim**

**Grab your double rep bonus on all voting on all Skyrim tagged questions for the week!**

Comment: I don't think we could implement this ourselves in any reasonable way.

Comment: You could maybe have something where either you or a group of users offer bounties to the best question(s) in [tag] asked within the past [time-frame].  Maybe users could offer to give the bounty so they can choose the game to promote playing.  I'd be ok offering a prize to best Dungeon Defenders Awakened question when it releases next year.  If we plan it out, we can avoid having too many "contests" at one time.

Comment: @Batophobia I'm sure there are ways we could make something like this work. Currently all of the suggestions promote chat or meta, and none of them really address the need for new users asking questions about games. While I like the idea of us gaming together, I'd like to see more of an effort put into growing our user base.

Comment: Movies&TV does [topic challenges](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/challenge), perhaps something similar?

Comment: @Robotnik Yeah exactly. Something that drives asking questions on the main site is what I'd like to see.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to see another [Holiday Bounty Giveaway](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5560/1351) this year (and would be willing to put up some rep for it too).  Unfortunately, I'm a little too busy to also organize this year, though.