# Screenshot of the Week contest #1

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*previous contest | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14773)*

---

Welcome to the first edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

As part of our community building efforts, we’ve decided to go ahead with [Joachim’s well received suggestion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14685/8350) of starting a weekly screenshot post.

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question. One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please! We will accept submissions for a week, until **21:00 UTC of 2019-12-4**, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone. After the end of the second week, at 21:00 UTC of 2019-12-11, we will count **upvotes only** to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

For this first week, we won’t have a dedicated theme; so it doesn’t matter if your screenshot is comedy, funny glitches, beautiful landscape shots, your Minecraft castle: let your imaginations run wild and vote for your favourites!

Just remember, Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here. As an additional rule, please avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

Finally, as this is our first Screenshot of the Week, we invite you to share any theme ideas, suggestions about the format, rules, concerns or anything else you might think of, in order to improve the following weeks’ editions.

Comment: Thanks for starting this. Does the aspect ratio matter? If the winning screenshot gets exposition on the main page, does it need to 'fit' within what I assume is a div of predetermined size? (I realize cropping is an option, but it might harm the composition.)

Comment: @Joachim The aspect ratio currently doesn't matter, since we don't have that photo widget that PHOTO.SE has. We're going to gauge the popularity of this over the first few weeks, and if it proves popular, then we'll reach out to SE about getting that widget on Arqade.

Comment: @Joachim Right now we cannot display winning posts on the main site, so they will be featured on the next Screenshot of the Week post instead. For now, there are no restrictions on aspect ratio or size for screenshots. You could say this is a bit of a trial period, partially to gauge the community's interest in this type of contest, and partially to get it started without having to wait for the network to enable the ability to display screenshots on the main site like Photography does.

Comment: Dangit, @Wipqozn beat me to it.

Comment: A suggestion: It may be convenient to have the deadlines / timestamps for submissions and voting included in the start post, since otherwise you would have to calculate them yourself by comparing the post time of the starting post and the current date.

Comment: **What happens in case of a tie?** The second week gets extended until the next upvote (which might be hard to trace)? Do we give the earlier or the most recent entry an extra vote? Will there be a new thread with only those two entries asking for new votes?

Comment: Will there be another one? This was asked 7 days ago ;)

Comment: @TravisJ We're going to let the voting period end before starting the next one. If people really like the idea of a submission week every week, we'll do overlapping contests in the future.

Comment: @Wrigglenite - So, maybe biweekly? :D I think this is neat! Ooh, once a fortnight :)

Comment: Presuming the current level of participation is sufficient to continue: Will there be specific categories for future themes? Will there be options to vote for them? Would a rotating schedule be prefered instead?

Comment: @BoogaRoo Eventually, yes, we'll have specific categories... for now, we're planning on having a few unthemed weeks to see if this type of contest keeps people interested over time.

Comment: @Wrigglenite can you please accept winner's answer? This will officially finalize results

Comment: @arghtype Derp, can't believe I forgot

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'll kick things off with this Farfetch'd giving me the biggest evils in [pokemon-sword-shield](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sword-shield):

[image: Wild Farfetch'd using Leer]

Comment: Seems like you're our cardinal champion, Robotnik, congratulations! (It's *obvious* it's only because you were the first to upload :)

Comment: @Joachim - thanks! I didn't expect to win haha. Perhaps for round 2 I'll wait a few days to post...

Answer (score 15):

I present Excalibur Umbra, practicing sword stances by moonlight, from the game [warframe](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warframe). Click for enlarged version.

[image: Excalibur Umbra practicing sword stances]

Comment: I remember seeing this screenshot as it was posted, not thinking much about it, as I didn't play Warframe back then. Now when I randomly remembered this thread, years later, as a Warframe player with hundreds of hours in-game, I can finally appreciate how beautiful this screenshot is.

Answer (score 15):

Re-building landmarks from Dubai in Minecraft for a community server

[image: Dubai landmarks]

Left to right: [Cayan Tower](http://www.som.com/FILE/21201/cayantower_372x372_timgriffith_06.jpg?w=300&h=300&m=e), [Emirates Towers](http://images.skyscrapercenter.com/building/emirates-tower-two_terri-meyer-boake3.jpg), [Burj Khalifa](https://images.adsttc.com/media/images/59eb/8a55/b22e/38dd/0500/0155/medium_jpg/Burj_Khalifa_SOM_exterior_%28c%29_Nick_Merrick_for_Hedrich_Blessing_%2810%29.jpg?1508608588)

Comment: That's pretty sick!

Comment: @TimmyJim Thanks! It took an eternity to build, especially the one on the left. :)

Answer (score 15):

Just a Subaru BRZ with an Itasha Livery of Hatsune Miku drifting in [need-for-speed-payback](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-payback).

[image]

Answer (score 14):

While blowing up things and freeing the towns in [just-cause-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/just-cause-3), i came across the perfect vehicle, which i took immediately to the garage to have it registered:

[image: The perfect vehicle]

Sadly, they refused to do so. I still wonder why.

Answer (score 13):

My humble starting base in Subnautica: compact, self-sufficient, and with a nice view

[image: Screenshot of my base!]

Answer (score 12):

Recent news about [snowstorm in Grand Canyon](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS773US773&biw=1536&bih=722&tbm=isch&sxsrf=ACYBGNRk9zazbdXmje-UGP98uAI6UxBFow%3A1575432404806&sa=1&ei=1DDnXeHzMMbk-gSp1afoAg&q=snowstorm%20in%20grand%20canyon%20december%202019&oq=snowstorm%20in%20grand%20canyon%20december%202019&gs_l=img.3...79229.85513..85761...0.0..0.83.1388.21......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......35i39j0i7i30j0i8i30j0i24j0i5i30.PaxHNvVDloM&ved=0ahUKEwjhreyGj5vmAhVGsp4KHanqCS0Q4dUDCAc&uact=5) reminded me of this place from [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn)

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I’d like to show off a shiny Patrat from [pokemon-go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-go) that is doing a superhero landing

[image: Shiny patrat, superhero landing]

Answer (score 9):

This epic kill in [world-of-tanks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-tanks), Normandy

[image]

Comment: Imagine seeing that on the WWII battlefield...

Comment: which tank was destroyed? Would be light armor tank, due to AMD gun :D

Comment: @damadam it was a Skorpion G on ~50HP, but he was already aiming at me at that moment, could've easily been an epic fail :)

Answer (score 9):

Say what you will about [assassins-creed-unity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-unity), but the colours and lighting are phenomenal:

[image: Arno listening in on some intriguing NPC banter]

Answer (score 9):

Took a photo of a scenic autumn evening in [fallout-76](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-76)

[image]

Comment: Y'know, for all it's faults, Fallout 76 has some nice scenery.

Comment: I love that in-game screenshots are incorporated into F76's loading screens. I have photographed so many vistas, but hey one post per contest

Answer (score 8):

I was playing [Borderlands 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-2) and encountered TWO ultra-rare "loot midget" enemies named Jimmy Jenkins at the same time. I'm still not sure of the spawn rate, but I've only seen it four times in seven years. I count this as two of those sightings.

[image: Two dead Jimmy Jenkins loaderbots]

Note: I was using the unfinished mission "Doctor's Orders" to increase chances for loot midgets, but wasn't specifically trying to find any particular type.

Comment: If this is in the Wildlife Exploitation Preserve, right after you defeat one Ultimate Badass Loader, then iis really common to find loot midgets and loot jenkins there, for whatever the reason. It's been a common source of grinding after you reach the OP lvls and need better guns.

Answer (score 7):

[pokemon-sword-shield](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sword-shield) gets pretty dark...

[image: tanoshii?]