# Screenshot of the Week contest #2

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14741) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14807)*

---

Welcome to the second edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Robotnik's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14742/143571) of an intimidating wild duck took the first spot with 16 upvotes! Here it is in all its beauty:

[image: Wild Farfetch'd using Leer]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question. One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please! We will accept submissions for a week, until **19:00 UTC of 2019-12-19**, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone. After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2019-12-26, we will count **upvotes only** to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

As with the first week, this contest won’t have a dedicated theme; feel free to post any screenshot that you think is cool, funny, lucky, or just worth sharing!

Just remember, Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here. As an additional rule, please avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

As a final note, we are still looking for any theme ideas, suggestions about the format, rules, concerns or anything else you might think of, in order to improve the following weeks’ editions. If you think you have some nice idea, post a comment on this question.

Comment: I've been taking fancy screenshots for years, but I have no one to share them with. The time has come!

Comment: Theme could be a "War Photographers Journal", where people post in-game photos of war games with a journalistic bent/narrative.

Comment: I would like to see themes that cover broad ideas. Stuff like: Humorous, Dramatic, Landscapes, Creativity, Wildlife, Horror, Glitches/Bugs, etc... That way someone can contribute without needing to have any particular game on hand.

Comment: Robotnik's latest submission leads me to a question regarding image manipulation. Obviously that screenshot could benefit from some adjustments. How much manipulation would be acceptable for the contest? I think cropping, brightness/contrast, and privacy focused edits(removing player names) would be fine by me.

Comment: @BoogaRoo - All the standard adjustments you list (cropping, blurring of PII, brightness/contrast edits) should be ok. When an edit starts to add something more to a screenshot is where we should draw the line: filters, superimposing other images, adding text etc, should be disallowed. This competition is just supposed to be a little bit of fun, not a photoshop skills test or meme compilation :)

Comment: What about Ansel filters?

Comment: @Smock Are you referring to vignette effects that darken the screen around the edge? Or are you asking about filters built into video card drivers from Nvidia that are applied as you play the game?

Comment: @BoogaRoo I meant the effects you can apply in game using the Ansel integration (using the nvidia engine to take photos in game)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> "Bubbles! Bubbles! My bubbles."
>
> <sub>Bubbles, Finding Nemo</sub>

Just keep flying in [no-mans-sky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-mans-sky).

[image: Bubble Planet, No Man's Sky]

Comment: Oooh, no high-res version?

Comment: @Joachim Sadly no :(

Answer (score 9):

> Aah, you were at my side, all along. My true mentor... My guiding moon-broccoli...

[bloodborne](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bloodborne)

[image]

Comment: Love it. I have no idea what's going on, but it's just bizarre.

Comment: @BoogaRoo What do you mean you have no idea what's going on? It's *obvious* it's a humanoid cauliflower-headed monster just out for a stroll in his skull garden :P

Comment: @Wondercricket Monster? This is all-mighty protagonist on his glorious quest to get all achievements!

Answer (score 9):

They may have lost their instruments, but the band must play on!
Life is hard on Medici under the brutal thumb of oppression in [Just Cause 3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/just-cause-3).
[image: Just Cause3 invisible band instruments]

Answer (score 9):

This hobbit in [lord-of-the-rings-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings-online) understands whats going on.

[image]

Comment: 'First of them is that I can't seem to find my face today..'

Comment: "It would be  easier to find my face if I had my hands!"

Comment: "I wonder where I put that ring of power..."

Comment: @Wondercricket Oh, *that*'s how it works! Or maybe she's wearing a frock made out of a particularly hard-to-render-invisible fabric..

Answer (score 9):

Spending a final moment of silence with Quirrel, in [hollow-knight](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hollow-knight).

[image: The Knight, sitting with Quirrel by the Blue Lake]

Answer (score 7):

Just started replaying some of the Pokemon games. Getting ready to catch Regirock in Pokemon Ruby

[image: Regirock's Cave]

Answer (score 7):

Stormbird [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn)

[image: Stormbird]

Answer (score 6):

Leg swept, defense ready.

[image]

<sub>[Tower Watch](https://oyster.ignimgs.com/mediawiki/apis.ign.com/destiny/8/89/Tower_Watch.jpg) at the [Tower](https://destiny.fandom.com/wiki/Tower_(Destiny)) in the original Destiny.</sub>

Comment: Praise the Traveler

Answer (score 6):

> *I wonder where I'll float next?*

[fallout-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-4)

[image: NPC in Barrel]

---

<sub>Quote reference: [xckd 1: Barrel - Part 1](https://xkcd.com/1/)</sub>

Comment: The lighting was terrible but still a funny moment...

Comment: Fallout 4 has so many references it's insane. Haven't seen this one, could you give me a hint where it is? :-)

Comment: @Rudolf - I think it was a random spawn not an explicit reference, but it was at that flooded quarry after you fix the pump

Comment: Ooh, thanks. Time for another visit then.

Answer (score 6):

I often joke that I'm like [Chitose from *Yuru Yuri*](https://yuruyuri.fandom.com/wiki/Chitose_Ikeda#Personality)

> [Chitose] has a gentle disposition, and often (especially when she takes her glasses off) **has various warm and fuzzy [Yuri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kThN3.gif) fantasies**, almost always pairing Kyōko together with Ayano, **which often leads to near-fatal nosebleeds.**

So while playing [stardew-valley](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stardew-valley)

[image: It's taste reminds me of yuri]

[what do you suppose will happen next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kThN3.gif)

Answer (score 6):

Just a bit testdriving with the Opel Ascona 400 in Dirt Rally 2.0

[image: Just some cruising]

Answer (score 5):

> If you want something done right do it yourself.

[image: duplicate umbras]

Managed to duplicate my character multiple times due to a bug in the latest update for [warframe](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warframe) so I could perform all 4 roles on my spaceship.

Answer (score 5):

I guess that's what double white lines are for...
[euro-truck-simulator-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euro-truck-simulator-2)

[image]

Comment: This photo is semi-satisfying

Answer (score 4):

[pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon) Drampa is a placid savage

[image: Savage]

Answer (score 3):

Uhm, something looks Fishy here....

[image]