# Screenshot of the week contest #3

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14773) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14828)*

---

Welcome to the third edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Wondercricket's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14776/143571) of a bubbly alien landscape took the first spot with 12 upvotes! Here it is in all its beauty:

[image: Bubble Planet, No Man's Sky]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question. One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please! Please note that limited modifications to submitted screenshots are allowed, like simple filters, but not adding other images or text. We will accept submissions for a week, until **19:00 UTC of 2020-01-03**, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone. After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-01-10, we will count **upvotes only** to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

We're looking for suggestions for a theme to use in the next contest, so if you have any cool ideas, please post them in a comment on this question. For this week, there will be no specific theme, so any screenshot is allowed! When suggesting a theme, try to avoid something unique to a single game or series, and go for more general ideas like "funny", "horror", or "recursion".

Just remember, Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here. As an additional rule, please avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

Comment: Theme idea: glitches and bugs

Comment: Theme idea: Wildlife

Comment: Theme idea: Space Exploration

Comment: Would there ever be the opportunity for GIFs to be supported in a weekly contest? I have some excellent ragdoll videos I would love to show

Comment: Theme Idea: Scenery / Cool Graphics

Comment: Theme Idea: Modding/Mods

Comment: Theme Idea: Character Customisation

Comment: Theme Idea: Robots/Synths/AIs

Comment: Less Conventional Theme Idea: Loading Screens

Comment: @Joachim How funny would it be for the winning screenshot of loading screens if Arqade got the home-page widget, since a lot of game's loading screens typically have in-game tips. "Here is our weekly useful tip for this specific game. Come back tomorrow for the same tip!"

Comment: @Wondercricket Maybe we should require them to be useful IRL, e.g. "Become friends with someone, and they may allow you to take certain things from their home."

Comment: @Joachim Or "Most shops are open from about 8am to 8pm. If a shop is closed, wait until morning... or pick the lock and break in."

Comment: @Wondercricket :D exactly!

Comment: A loading screen would be... extremely boring. It's a screenshot that someone else pre-assembled for you.

Comment: @Wrigglenite With that said, should we also refrain from submitting photos that are automatically generated? My submission for this contest is that case, but not sure if how they should be handled in future contests

Comment: @Wondercricket on the topic of IRL loading screen tips, you would really like Reddit.com/r/Outside

Comment: @Wondercricket Sure, some games do auto-screenshots, but they are still in-game material. They may not be "creative" in the same sense as a hand-picked screenshot, but I don't think that's a good reason to exclude them. In fact, they might even allow for shots that would be otherwise impossible without recording the whole game as a video. I think they should be allowed.

Comment: @Wrigglenite True, they are predefined. But how many of them are there, and how many have we seen? Some are semi-randomized, allowing for surprising juxtapositions between image and text. Many are quit rare, if not unique; some are beautiful. Those considerations made me suggest it. I think these limitations can allow for a fascinating series of images.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A scenic aurora in [the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim)

[image: scenic aurora]

Comment: Thank you for taking me down nostalgia lane

Comment: I started a new playthrough to get the achievements I missed. I forgot how much there was to do in this game!

Answer (score 11):

Just as the Zerg start to break through my line, the *Hyperion* shows up! [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2)

[image: A battlefield]

Answer (score 9):

That moment when you enter a new location for the first time. [death-stranding](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-stranding)

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Just another amazing auto-snap in [final-fantasy-15](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-15)

[image: Final Fantasy XV]

Answer (score 7):

Spittin' into the wind in [castle-crashers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castle-crashers)

[image: camels]