# Screenshot of the week contest #4

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14807) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14863)*

---

Welcome to the fourth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [PausePause's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14815/8350) of a scenic aurura took the first spot with 12 upvotes! Here it is in all its beauty:

[image: A scenic aurora, Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question. One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please! Please note that limited modifications to submitted screenshots are allowed, like simple filters, but not adding other images or text. We will accept submissions for a week, until **19:00 UTC of 2020-01-17**, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone. After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-01-24, we will count **upvotes only** to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

We're looking for suggestions for a theme to use in the next contest, so if you have any cool ideas, please post them in a comment on this question. For this week, there will be no specific theme, so any screenshot is allowed! When suggesting a theme, try to avoid something unique to a single game or series, and go for more general ideas like "funny", "horror", or "recursion".

Just remember, Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here. As an additional rule, please avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

Comment: Would Ansel filters(or other video card based filters) be acceptable? No opinion here. I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: Theme suggestion: Winter

Comment: @BoogaRoo I personally don't see a problem with them. As the last few contests have shown, it's not just the 'pretty' pictures that get upvoted. Besides, some users will already have an edge with their better hardware, and we can't really set a baseline for that.

Comment: @Joachim Good point. I doubt I would even recognize if the filters were in use unless I knew the game already anyway. Plus, I imagine some people will play with the filters they like turned on and may not have a way to retake a screenshot without them. I see no harm in allowing the filters. It's not like there's prize money at stake.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[dark-souls-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls-3)

[image: Me in Set of Thorns with Black Knight Axe in Irithyll of the Boreal Valley]

Comment: For a moment, I was expecting the person standing there to be Gotham's Commissioner Gordon!

Answer (score 14):

When playing around with mods in [blade-and-soul](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blade-and-soul) goes south, you get the most scenic vistas.

[image]

Comment: Hehehe, looks like something in Willy Wonka's factory!

Comment: @BoogaRoo I'm so glad I was not the only one who thought that

Answer (score 13):

[star-wars-jedi-fallen-order](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-jedi-fallen-order)

I used to be a Jedi like you, but then I took a saber to the knee ... and foot ... and shoulder.

[image: Cal with double-saber]

Answer (score 11):

Aloy takes on a Scrapper at dusk [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn)

[image: Aloy takes on a Scrapper]

Answer (score 9):

My [rust](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rust) fortress as seen from above.

[image: Rust fortress]

Answer (score 9):

How about a lime green "gummy bear" B-17E bomber for Willy Wonka's air force? [war-thunder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/war-thunder)

[image: Lime green B-17E]

Comment: This reminded of the [Gummy Bear Song](https://youtu.be/astISOttCQ0?t=10)

Answer (score 7):

derping around in [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Hiding in plain sight during playground games (you can only get on the roof by making the jump the player behind me is currently missing).

[forza-horizon-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-horizon-4)

[image: hiding in plain sight]