# Screenshot of the week contest #5: Glitches and Bugs

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14828) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14912)*

---

Welcome to the fifth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [arghtype's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14831/127901) of a dark soul's rendition of a bat signal took the first spot with 23 upvotes! Here it is in all its beauty:

[image: Arghtype's screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question. After a few clarifications on previous competitions, we've compiled this handy list of requirements, so please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-02-03, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-02-10, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

---

## Theme

This week's theme is: **Glitches and Bugs**

Got an interesting, funny, absurd or awkward screenshot that showcases a bug, glitch or other non-intended game behavior? That's this week is all about!

---

Comment: Theme idea: *Moments before Disaster*. e.g. Mining a block just before falling into lava in Minecraft, Blocking yourself with no escape in Bomberman, etc etc

Comment: Are animated gifs of clips allowed? Sometimes it is hard to show a bug or glitch with just one image.

Comment: @TravisJ, good question. Ill get back to you shortly with an answer

Comment: @TravisJ, after discussing with the other mods, right now we want to keep it to just screenshots to keep the playing field even for those who can't create animated gifs. might be cool to do a specific theme for animated stuff sometime

Comment: @Dragonrage - Okay, thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: Theme suggestion: landscapes

Comment: Theme suggestion: skins and customizations

Comment: Theme suggestion: stunning vistas

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image: a truck floating on a river in Euro Truck Simulator]

beep beep

Comment: when you are too tired to walk on the water

Answer (score 14):

This deathcam was a little too close for comfort in [team-fortress-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2)

[image: TF2]

Comment: Nemesis with visible teeth? Seems familiar https://static0.gamerantimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Resident-Evil-3-regional-pricing.jpg

Comment: @arghtype oh jeez hahaha I didn't even think of that :D

Answer (score 13):

Nothing special, just some guy sitting next to the bench in [payday-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payday-2)

[image: guy sitting next to the bench]

Comment: I've got one from the time [I fell through the entire map](https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/595891928418236297/FD0D754012791C7DC65B30BA1337F12EFDBCB2F8/) I think on Escape: Overpass or something like that

Answer (score 11):

In [borderlands-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-2), my nuke turret hit this guy so hard he got stuck in the wall!

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Bugs you say? With [92 original and valid Minecraft bugs reported](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-169113?jql=reporter%20%3D%20FaRo1%20and%20project%3DMC%20and%20resolution%20in%20(Done%2CFixed%2CUnresolved)) I feel especially qualified for this! (But I'm not as crazy as [this guy](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-170076?jql=reporter%20%3D%20Marcono1234%20and%20project%3DMC%20and%20resolution%20in%20(Done%2CFixed%2CUnresolved)) with 734 bugs.)

I'm not sure if this is technically a bug, but you can actually sleep outside of beds in Minecraft. It requires a bit of skill to get right, but with enough sideways momentum at the exact moment of entering the bed, you can bounce on it while sleeping and bounce out of it. I used this to create this screenshot of a watery grave:

[image]

Here are some more awesome bug screenshots:

- Skeleton with creeper armour: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b8OWhuOXQkqxHPgT8MiOPBhm7mRXZjrr
- When pigs fly: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PdTnU3HnLe5BYQ-h9gPTSwOIzFgT1Jb5
- Yoshi has a long tonuge: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15WPEhVvCbdYoT0aADGN94uiRVaqs2kHf
- Jesus in Temple Run 2: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eRoQKEMdBfWQqD8D4i3ep_j9A3r88IR0
- Undead dogs: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-7UitZW1An1W6aITdnlHOjBciSf9irO_

And some that are not made by me:

- Interesting keybind in key rebind challenge: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E-hOPcCZlnvahkN4DkP2ZbIXaQ9n90zy
- Iskall's nightmare, diorite water: https://bugs.mojang.com/secure/attachment/65981/2014-06-18_12.22.50.png
- Gigantic slime blocks: https://bugs.mojang.com/secure/attachment/58085/2014-02-23_16.24.54.png
- Broken turtles: https://bugs.mojang.com/secure/attachment/239364/2019-09-27_18.19.29.png

Comment: One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!

Comment: One post per person? But I have so many awesome bug images. :( Alright, I'll delete all except one.

Comment: Just save them for another competition :)

Comment: Nah, I have way more awesome non-bug related screenshots. I'll have enough content for the other competitions. Is my entry OK like this now? Or should I add a disclaimer that people shouldn't vote based on the links?

Comment: @FabianRöling 'Glitches and Bugs' will most likely be a recurring screenshot theme ;). And yeah that's fine for now

Comment: BTW, I found out recently that this bed bouncing while sleeping is actually a Bukkit bug.

Answer (score 10):

In [blade-and-soul](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blade-and-soul), you can see a lot of stuff outside the map, or when you glitch into unintended areas.

So many things, like, the fire forgetting how it works:
[image: That's not how fire works]

Answer (score 7):

Some **very** well-watered trees in StoneHearth

[image: Trees in water]

A while ago in one of the earlier builds of the game, you could still plant trees anywhere, even if there was water there. While I don't have any photos, I remember once you cut the trees down, it left a big hole where the water should be.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Peebee leaning against an invisible railing]

I posted this in chat a while back as a demonstration of just how broken Mass Effect: Andromeda was, even in small ways.  There's more where this came from.  For reference, Peebee is supposed to be leaning her arms against the railing, not awkwardly trying to sit on it.

Answer (score 6):

Abstraction in [the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim), when the lighting was extremely buggy.

[image]

Comment: looks like a normal day in skyrim

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of an easy target..

Comment: for others like myself: this screenshot is not vertical and actually has over exposed part to the right

Comment: First I thought this was an actual photo, just with a smaller than usual colour palette (lines in the sky). I was wondering why you called this "extremely buggy lighting" until I saw the right half.

Comment: @FabianRöling Funny that 'why on earth would he post an actual photo' was not the first thing you were wondering about :)

Answer (score 6):

This is what happens when you accidentally portal outside the map on the Plains of Eidolon. [warframe](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warframe)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**C&C Renegade**... oh I loved that game - and my Spongebob skins for the explosives.

Here someone tried to drive that tank over the wall and got stuck on it. At least it can't get stolen there.

[image]