# Screenshot of the week contest #6: Wildlife

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14863) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14932)*

---

Welcome to the sixth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [@Unionhawk's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14866/127901) of a semi-tractor defying physics by parking on top of the water, took the first spot in a close race with 14 upvotes!

[image: Unionhawk's screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question. After a few clarifications on previous competitions, we've compiled this handy list of requirements, so please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-02-17, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-02-24, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

---

## Theme

This week's theme is: **Wildlife**

Got a game that has an amazing array of wildlife? Ever wanted to be a wildlife photographer? Here's your chance! Show us the most interesting wildlife you can find!

Comment: Would Monster Hunter monsters that you unlock later into the game fall under the spoiler rule?

Comment: @Riley, talked with some people who are more familiar with the game, and the general consensus was that you should be ok to post pictures of those

Comment: If we dont get at least *one* from Pokemon Snap I'll be disappointed

Comment: @BoogaRoo, i was kinda surprised as well. i also expected more entries given how popular the category seemed to be

Comment: General Suggestion: Perhaps adding a heads up about the *next* week's theme could help participation. Having some lead time may be helpful for people without a lot of free time to try to get a new screenshot if they don't have one already fitting that theme.

Comment: @BoogaRoo, good idea. next one wont have a theme i dont think. probably going to alternate between themed and unthemed

Comment: I think that's an even better adjustment. It would certainly take the pressure off the answerers half the time, plus give them time to get their shots in order for the next themed deadline about three weeks out.

Comment: Theme suggestion: selfies (close up of protagonist's face + something interesting on background)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I started [sekiro-shadows-die-twice](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sekiro-shadows-die-twice) last week, and I've been hiding from local wildlife since then.

[image: snake]

Comment: That’s a large nope rope

Comment: @Dragonrage It's also known as the infamous danger noodle

Comment: Hazard spaghetti?

Comment: Naww it's just a friendly boop noodle!

Comment: Just started replaying this again, and I had an interesting encounter. It was this section, but the Serpent was thrashing wildly, the entire time, as my made my way back from the checkpoint. I needed new pants after dealing with that.

Answer (score 14):

Have at ye! ([subnautica](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subnautica))

[image]

Comment: I hope no reaper leviathans were harmed in the making of this screenshot.

Comment: Harmed, but I was harmed more brutally milliseconds later.

Answer (score 12):

Back when I first tried out shaders in Minecraft, I managed to take this nice picture of a bunny on a mountain, looking into the distance.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Say, Beedle, do you have any bear chow for my new buddy here? [zelda-breath-of-the-wild](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-breath-of-the-wild)

[image: Link riding a bear in Zelda: Breath of the Wild]

Comment: Sadly, they [won't let me keep him](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0NFo.jpg) in the stable. Ah well.

Answer (score 6):

A family of Delicate Pobbers I rescued during my conservation efforts in the Orb Vallis in [warframe](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warframe)

[image: Delicate Pobbers]