# Screenshot of the Week Contest #7

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14912) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14966)*

---

Welcome to the seventh edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [@arghtype's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14913/127901) of hiding from a very large danger noodle from [sekiro-shadows-die-twice](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sekiro-shadows-die-twice), took the first spot with 18 upvotes!

[image: arghtype's screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question. After a few clarifications on previous competitions, we've compiled this handy list of requirements, so please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-03-02, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-03-09, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

---

## Theme

There is no theme for this week's contest so send us your best screenshot you have of anything.

Our next contest (#8) will feature a theme of scenery, so get your screenshots ready in preparation!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So I have a screenshot of the same system as Unionhawk is in, but from the tourist destination aptly named *The View*. I took this screenshot during the community event [Distant Worlds 2](https://forums.frontier.co.uk/threads/distant-worlds-2-a-journey-of-discovery.452358/) of [elite-dangerous](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elite-dangerous). No editing done to this screenshot, the planet really looks like that.

[image: Third person screenshot from The View]

Comment: I was actually saving my The View shot for next week's Scenery theme but I guess I gotta find another one now lol

Comment: @Unionhawk Sorry about that, you made me go back down memory lane of DW2.

Answer (score 12):

Here's my buddy next to me in [war-thunder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/war-thunder) driving a Panzer IV H. Who knew the "H" stood for helium?

[image: Flying tank, the Panzer IV H!]

Comment: I would say H stands for "Hover"!

Comment: are you sure its not hydrogen?

Comment: @Dragonrage Nah. Hydrogen's too flammable. Surely the Germans would not be using hydrogen to float a vehicle [with people in it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindenburg_disaster)!

Comment: @BoogaRoo hydrogen is flammable? but its used to make water

Answer (score 11):

I managed to snap this soldier guarding a helicopter in [call-of-duty-modern-warfare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-modern-warfare) as the level fades out.

[image: Cod: MW2]

Answer (score 11):

My [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) test world might be a little crazy. Just maybe.

[image]

It's the third world I ever created in this game and it's a bit like a piece of living art: Whenever I want to test something, I usually just do it right where I stand, without considering preserving anything most of the time. But I also don't go out of my way to remove anything. This results in a gigantic conglomerate of everything that spans thousands of blocks in all directions. Older things are less likely to still work or even exist at all, but occasionally I still find contraptions that are years old and still intact, despite being right in the middle of this insanity.
I almost never create new worlds to test something, that's why I completely ruined the world multiple times already, but I only restored partial backups once or twice. I downgraded from 1.9 to 1.6, repeatedly from snapshots to releases, had killing command blocks set to repeat and tested world-corrupting bugs in this world.
I could (and occasionally do) wander around in this world for hours, re-discovering ancient projects and getting ideas for new ones. You might also spot some of my gamingSE answers in this screenshot. ;)

Comment: I would love to see more of it. Do you have a gallery of screenshots of this world?

Comment: @Joachim I have a super old tour of it on my YouTube channel, but that includes barely anything that is in there right now. I want to make a new one one day, but for now I have just recorded a silent clip for you: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G612PTvwJnbT6nK54_LUc_dosxxBv33y That's not even remotely close to being all of it. Pretty much every arbitrary round coordinate you can teleport yourself to (like 1000 100 -1000) looks similar and this doesn't even include the sponge beacon, the cobblestone wither cage generator, The last block™, …

Comment: Thank you, that was marvellous! I don't really recognize anything - I'm not that familiar with Minecraft (currently getting into modding Minetest, however) - but the scenery is wonderfully weird in a dream-logic manner, and the fly-through reminds me of some animations I made years ago ([1](https://joachimbeens.com/phenomenal/sheets/works/video_mem.html),[2](https://vimeo.com/153824437). I love those aesthetics.

Comment: With a bit of effort I was able to find things that were probably over 4 years old, less than 50 blocks away from the center. So yes, some things do survive a long time.

Comment: Your screenshot has disappeared @FabianRöling I recommend using imgur instead of dropbox for images.

Comment: @Riley It's still there for me in a private/incognito tab. Unlike my previous Google Drive link, this Dropbox link is supposed to never break. I wouldn't know why it should ever do that. Maybe it's an adblock issue on your side?

Comment: Yep, my bad. @FabianRöling Privacy Badger blocked Dropbox outright. Sorry about that.

Comment: looks like my test world back when i played a lot of minecraft

Comment: I want to free up some space on Google Drive, so I moved the video here: https://youtu.be/bJqC_BNl4U4

Answer (score 10):

Why dual wield just pistols when you can triple wield a shotgun with them to camp even better in [counter-strike-source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-source)

[image]

Answer (score 10):

> “*It's only a model..*”

[image: *Shall I compare thee to a summer's day?*]

Trying to let *A Tale of Two Wastelands* and the *Flora Overhaul* play nice together in [fallout-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-3) let me venture through the **Capitalist Wasteland**, where everything is made out of billboards.

Comment: On second thought, let's not go to Capitalist Wasteland. It is a silly place

Comment: The... Capitalist Wasteland?

Answer (score 9):

HR 6164 in [elite-dangerous](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elite-dangerous) is an absolutely incredible system. It consists of a class O blue/white supergiant, 2 black holes, and a neutron star. This tourist installation is positioned right next to the [jet cone](http://www.astro.wisc.edu/news-events/featured-science/neutron-star-fires-powerful-jets) of HR 6164 C.

Or as someone in my discord put it, "what the heck is that giant death laser"

[image: tourist installation just outside HR 6164 C]

Comment: I grabbed a screenshot from The View (HR 6164 ABC 1) as well that I was going to save for next time's scenery theme but I guess I need to find a new one https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/673691940562272308/682012442351501382/20200225183244_1.jpg

Answer (score 8):

It looks like this [team-fortress-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2) death-cam wanted to be a batman transition a little too much...

[image: Swirly boy]

Comment: *My eyes! The goggles do nothing!*

Answer (score 6):

Jolly Cooperation with Braveheart in [dark-souls-2-sotfs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls-2-sotfs)

[image: Jolly Coop]