# Screenshot of the Week Contest #8: Scenery

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14932) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14994)*

---

Welcome to the eighth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [@Riley's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14944/) of a the view from an [elite-dangerous](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elite-dangerous) tourist destination known simply as *[The View](https://www.edsm.net/en/system/id/21566/name/HR+6164)*, took the first spot with 18 upvotes!

[image: Riley's screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question. After a few clarifications on previous competitions, we've compiled this handy list of requirements, so please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-03-16, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-03-23, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

---

## Theme

This week's theme is: **Scenery**

Got a game with amazing scenery? Epic landscapes, gorgeous sunsets? Show us the best view you can find!

Comment: They're all so good!

Comment: I also like that last week's winner is basically an entry for this week's theme

Comment: I guess I'll play Super Mario Galaxy 2 again, just to create a screenshot. :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I first played [shadow-of-the-colossus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadow-of-the-colossus) way back in the day on the PS2. I felt a wave of nostalgia when I rode into this vast plain on the PS4.

[image: Shadow of the colossus world]

Comment: Never played it, but it's been on my "to do" list of games forever.

Comment: @BoogaRoo Easily one of the top games I’ve played. Assuming you have a PS4, it’s free this month as apart of the PS4’s free monthly games for PS+ subscribers :)

Answer (score 14):

Tranquil sunset near Devil's Thirst [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn)

[image: Tranquil sunset]

Comment: I really need to play this game - I got it for Xmas but it's still on my 'to-do' list!

Comment: @Robotnik Put every game aside, kids to bed, or whatever you need to do - Horizon Zero Dawn is a MUST play it :P

Comment: @Robotnik I love it, which is one reason I have about 90 screenshots!

Comment: It's coming out on PC soon, so that's going to be fun

Answer (score 12):

I keep pausing and enjoying the scenery in [kingdom-come-deliverance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-come-deliverance).

[image]

> View on Rattay from the west.

<sup>(The compass and health bar have been cropped, and the reticule cloned away, since this is from before I started using Ansel.)</sup>

Answer (score 12):

View from the beginning of the mission Halo in Halo CE: Anniversary

[image]

Answer (score 11):

After falling off the side of the Firelands I was treated to a spectacular view in [world-of-warcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-warcraft)
[image: Ragnaros' Domain]

Comment: Ah, I remember that. I was too stupid to control my racials and jumped off the cliffs pretty often. Lovely view. <3

Answer (score 9):

> DeLacy uniform november india, it's good to have you with us commander.

[image: Asteroid base near a white star]

(this is an [elite-dangerous](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elite-dangerous) view from Harvard Base, an asteroid base that orbits 14 Ls away from HIP 83506 A, a class B blue/white star)

Answer (score 9):

> Foggy Bottom Station, D.C. 'Capital Wasteland', circa 2277

[image: Fallout 3 - Foggy Bottom Station]

[fallout-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-3) still holds up to scrutiny 12 years later, thanks in part to [NMC's Texture pack.](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout3/mods/12056)*

---

<sub>* I have no affiliation with this mod</sub>

Answer (score 8):

Night falls over the Rocky Desert in [satisfactory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satisfactory)

[image: night-fall-rocky-desert]

Answer (score 7):

Approaching the sunset in [call-of-duty-modern-warfare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-modern-warfare)

[image: Call of Duty]]

Answer (score 4):

Link and Prince Sidon look over Zora's domain after calming divine beast Vah Ruta's raging deluge.
[zelda-breath-of-the-wild](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-breath-of-the-wild)

[image: Zora's Domain]

Answer (score 4):

Lake of Nine and Tyr's Temple in [god-of-war-2018](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/god-of-war-2018)

[image: lake-of-nine]

Answer (score -4):

The nicest place in [super-mario-galaxy-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-galaxy-2), with an [HD texture pack](https://forums.dolphin-emu.org/Thread-super-mario-galaxy-2-hd-texture-mod) and a few other graphical improvements, thanks to [dolphin-emulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dolphin-emulator).

[image]

It's even better with sound: [https://youtu.be/4cjfj3Fsr6g](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cjfj3Fsr6g)

This is the only place in SMG2 where a lens flare was used or in general anything more fancy in the sky than an animated texture.

I played about 30 levels again just to make this screenshot, because I had no save state that was further than world 4.

Comment: Heads up: submissions closed the other day. Might explain the downvotes

Comment: @Robotnik Oh weird, I diidn't see it at all until yesterday. Was the featured tag added to it too late or something like that?

Comment: It's never been featured... but we have had a lot of meta activity this week, perhaps it was pushed out of Hot Meta Posts?