# Screenshot of the Week Contest #9

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14966) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15013)*

---

Welcome to the ninth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Wondercricket's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14971/143571) of a foggy plain in Shadow of the Colossus took the first spot with 16 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question. After a few clarifications on previous competitions, we've compiled this handy list of requirements, so please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-03-30, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-04-06, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

---

## Theme

There is no theme to this week's contest, so go ahead and share your best screenshots!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks in the comments.

Comment: Theme suggestion: Shiny things! (Stuff that glows, glitters, and sparkles.)

Comment: Theme suggestion: 90s games (release date 1990-1999) (no HD remasters - let those pixels speak!)

Comment: @Robotnik You're opening a door of nostalgia with that theme

Comment: @Wondercricket I hope so!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Stanley finally got the memo to work from home, so now there's a new workforce at the office.
[image: Stanley Parable]

[the-stanley-parable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-stanley-parable)

Answer (score 14):

Alright, you [convinced me](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14972/28182). I started playing [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn) ...and it's as beautiful as they say.

> *Morning Mist*

[image: Horizon Zero Dawn]

Comment: You made a very wise decision :)

Answer (score 12):

[image: ACNH museum with a Coelacanth, an Oarfish, and a Football Fish]

The deep sea is terrifying, but the museum in [animal-crossing-new-horizons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-crossing-new-horizons) is incredible.

Comment: I uh, have a feeling we're going to be seeing a lot of this museum in screenshot of the week in the coming months, lol

Comment: Ooh, I bet my wife would like this. Good thing you posted it :)

Answer (score 12):

A round of beer for my crew at the Abyss Bar in [deep-rock-galactic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-rock-galactic). Gotta love those mugs!

[image]

Answer (score 11):

While giving [getting-over-it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/getting-over-it) a try and falling down for the first time, I was greeted with this very encouraging message:

[image: oof]

Answer (score 10):

Still enjoying fabulous locations in [sekiro-shadows-die-twice](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sekiro-shadows-die-twice)

[image]

Answer (score 8):

A little trip down memory lane in [half-life-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-life-2) in celebration of today's release of [half-life-alyx](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-life-alyx).

[image: Alyx acting all nonchalant after the events in her self-titled game]

Answer (score 8):

Since I heard about the last round too late, here another attempt for this screenshot:

The nicest place in [super-mario-galaxy-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-galaxy-2), with an [HD texture pack](https://forums.dolphin-emu.org/Thread-super-mario-galaxy-2-hd-texture-mod) and a few other graphical improvements, thanks to [dolphin-emulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dolphin-emulator).

[image]

It's even better with sound: [https://youtu.be/4cjfj3Fsr6g](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cjfj3Fsr6g)

This is the only place in SMG2 where a lens flare was used or in general anything more fancy in the sky than an animated texture.

I played about 30 levels again just to make this screenshot, because I had no save state that was further than world 4 and this is the last regular level.

Answer (score 7):

A Spongebob vehicle in **C&C Renegade**

(real vehicle with a self-made custom skin)

[image: vehicle looking like Spongebob in Renegade]

Answer (score 6):

A modest cabin by the road built by my team as a starting location in [rust](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rust)

[image: Small cabin by the road]