# Screenshot of the Week Contest #10

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14994) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15042)*

---

Welcome to the tenth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Batophobia's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15005) of the Companion Cube taking over office duties while Stanley works from home in [the-stanley-parable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-stanley-parable) took the first spot with 13 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question. After a few clarifications on previous competitions, we've compiled this handy list of requirements, so please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-04-13, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-04-20, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

---

## Theme

There is no theme to this week's contest, so go ahead and share your best screenshots!

Our next contest will have a "Moments Before Disaster" theme, so go ahead and cause some disasters to be ready for next time!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks in the comments.

Comment: Well, I guess it's time to update KSP...

Comment: Theme idea: Classic - game content must be 10+ years old

Comment: @Batophobia Gah! You won in the final few hours! Congratulations :)

Comment: My entry this week made me think of a good theme: Idle Animations.

Comment: Theme idea: Giant Monsters (Wrigglenight’s post made me think of this one)

Comment: Theme idea: A space/sci-fi theme. Epic space battles and far distant galaxies.

Comment: @Wondercricket Uuuhh, I have a good entry for that!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something about this skeleton seems more dangerous than usual…

[image]

This is actually not a resource pack. I teleported everything to me (`/tp @e @s`) in [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) and for some reason these two stuck together and the creeper's head was rotated in a very weird way that made it not visible in this screenshot (I think it was either 90° up and back, looking at the sky, or even upside down).

Answer (score 18):

Sparx saying hello in [spyro-reignited-trilogy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spyro-reignited-trilogy)

[image: Bored Sparx]

---

(Taken in the Winter Tundra - [spyro-2-riptos-rage](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spyro-2-riptos-rage) / [spyro-2-gateway-to-glimmer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spyro-2-gateway-to-glimmer))

Comment: Wow, just minutes before the end, you got another vote that put you on the same score as me. I _could_ win now by downvoting this, but that would be unfair.

Comment: @FabianRöling We only actually consider the upvotes.

Comment: @Wipqozn W h y ?

Comment: @FabianRöling One reason would to prevent people from doing exactly what you just suggested. Down voting other posts so theirs ranks higher.

Comment: @Fabian - looks like you had 16 anyway :-)

Answer (score 12):

Uhm, I can explain this...

[image: Minecraft at it's best]

Maybe 2000 Entities were a bit too much for testing purposes. Maybe.

[minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition)

Comment: I can explain it as well: Spawning random mobs. Also, here's a nice method to crash Minecraft before even just one more second of in-game time passes: `/setblock ~ ~ ~ repeating_command_block{auto:1,Command:"execute at @e run summon ender dragon"}` Even if you start in an empty world, you have 1048575 dragons in one spot after one second (or whatever that stretches to with lag), all pushing on each other. And if you start in a regular world, you get 1-3 amazing still images before the crash. If you want even more, duplicate "`at @e `".

Comment: The ghast is plotting something: https://i.ibb.co/6WbNXz6/a4b6c417-96eb-4159-b245-88deed00a634.png

Answer (score 11):

to those who post images from FPSs like *Counter Strike* or *Doom*. you call those guns? this is a gun you can have in [mothergunship](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mothergunship)

[image: THIS IS A GUN!]

Comment: I thought this is some platformer level design

Comment: This reminds me of [this scene](https://youtu.be/WWl8EbNN8NM?t=25) in the movie *Crocodile Dundee*, except with guns.

Answer (score 10):

Nice.  [oldschool-runescape](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oldschool-runescape)

[image: Nice]

Comment: gz, @@@@@@@@@@@@@@, etc

Comment: My hats off to you sir. I gave up after hitting lv86

Comment: @Wondercricket the pandemic has allowed me to work from home and in doing so, I afked from like 94 to 99 on my phone while working.  Redwoods worked perfectly for it.  You can really see the [spike in my Xp](https://crystalmathlabs.com/tracker/track.php?player=timmy_jim&skill=woodcutting&time=365d) in Woodcutting since the stay at home orders.

Answer (score 9):

A really big Teostra staring me down in [monster-hunter-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monster-hunter-world).

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This **BFD** in [doom-eternal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doom-eternal)

[image: Really Big Door]

Answer (score 7):

Something to cheer you up in times of isolation:

[image]

[kingdom-come-deliverance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-come-deliverance)

Answer (score 5):

Remakes these days... [final-fantasy-7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-7)

[image: FF7Remake]

Comment: I knew it was only a matter of time before seeing a screenshot of this beauty :)

Comment: What should I notice here?

Answer (score 5):

Art from a member of the Fighter's Guild in [the-elder-scrolls-4-oblivion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-4-oblivion)

[image: This is art]

Answer (score 5):

How's it hanging? @ [counter-strike-source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-source)

[image]

Comment: Are you... are you still playing on a 4x3 monitor?  Please say it isn't a CRT as well.

Comment: @MBraedley nah, it's just a very old screeny :D I found it in a backup from 2009 and I most likely had already a flat screen back then.