# Screenshot of the Week #11: Moments Before Disaster

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15013) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15079)*

---

Welcome to the eleventh edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Fabian Röling's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15019) of a creeper and a skeleton fusing in [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) took the first spot at the last minute with 16 upvotes! <sup>*Note that only upvotes are considered</sup>

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question. After a few clarifications on previous competitions, we've compiled this handy list of requirements, so please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-04-27, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-05-04, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

---

## Theme

The theme for this contest is "Moments Before Disaster". So go ahead and cause some disasters and submit your best for this week!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: I could submit my winning screenshot again this time. :D

Comment: Or essentially every single moment in [Slicedlime's "half-hearted hardcore" series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4ZS2guXqa_jOvWfeJjM6aXLITNpUFKEU) (except that that would not be my own screenshot).

Comment: Is there a way to see how many votes are cast in a specific thread in a specific period of time? I'm wondering if these second voting-only weeks are worth the wait, or maybe just make us lose momentum. Supposing that after the first week we add a week (or another amount of days) *from the moment the last valid entry was uploaded*, we could improve the rolling of the ball, so to speak. (Depending, naturally, on the moderators.)

Comment: @Joachim I think last week's results speak to the value of fixed week-long voting periods that don't depend on the timing of the last submission. To me, consistency and predictability are just as important as fairness for these events.

Comment: If people feel like these contests are too slow, what I would propose is overlapping contests. I.E. A new contest every week with the same voting protocol as we currently have. That said, I only think this would work if people could find the attention span  to juggle simultaneously running contests. I fear having two contests at the same time would draw attention away from the previous week's voting pool.

Comment: @BoogaRoo Yes, I thought about overlapping contests as well, but leave that up to the admins :) Mind that the underlying reason was not the pace of these contests necessarily, nor to mess with the consistency and predictability (which, indeed, are important aspects of fair contests), but simply wondering about the necessity of that second week. I feel that most if not all of the time the leading entry after the first week gets the worm.

Comment: @Joachim Certainly there are times where one entry is a runaway winner that's unlikely to be surpassed. I think there's an excellent example right in this week's current standings. I think it's incredibly unlikely that 8-10 votes will come in for the current 2nd and 3rd place entries without more also being cast for the Animal Crossing entry. From that standpoint, might as well call this one done. There's certainly a long-shot chance that one might catch up, but I seriously doubt that will happen.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[image: Showing off a caught bug, about to be attacked by a tarantula]

Comment: idk, this spider looks cute

Answer (score 19):

[image: Triple plane crash in War Thunder]
This is me vs. three enemy fighters in  [war-thunder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/war-thunder). I had just taken out the German fighter on the far right and started on the Swiss plane on the far left. That's when the Japanese fighter took out my tail control so I couldn't dodge. He came in too fast, over shot me, took out his teammate, and guaranteed nobody made it out alive. A fraction of a second later we were three fireballs.

Answer (score 15):

> [x-plane-11](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-plane-11) Southwest 2329 dual engine fire we are ditching in the Pacific.

[image: a 737 with dual engine fire headed into the ocean]

Comment: [Alternate flight deck view complete with checklist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyhgb.jpg)

Comment: Since it is moments before disaster, you did not make it?

Comment: @LoreFriendly I mean I made it into the Pacific Ocean and the game didn't score it a "crash"

Answer (score 14):

Got too greedy on a shortcut in [descenders](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/descenders).  About to smack into that tree at ~50kph

[image: Tree coming up]

Answer (score 9):

Sector cle... oh. @ [counter-strike-source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-source) with some help of [garrys-mod](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/garrys-mod)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You open this door and there are 79 monsters behind it. Oops. [dungeons-of-dredmor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-of-dredmor)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Nobody said that the screenshot couldn't be staged. ;)

[image]

Comment: I mean, I'm getting one together using the failures menu in X Plane so I certainly hope that's allowed

Comment: @Unionhawk I see nothing wrong with staging screenshots. Some of those easily take more work than regular gameplay!

Comment: I can't tell what's going on in this one

Comment: There are a ton of a mobs there that are called "zombie pigmen" or "zombified piglins" (depending on whether you play the latest release or the testing versions), which usually do nothing, but when you attack one of them, even if just accidentally, all of them get angry at you. And they are really strong. In this screenshot you can see the exact moment when I punched one of them with my bare hand while having no armour on and almost depleted health and hunger bars and while standing on a block that is supposed to be affected by gravity, but hasn't fallen yet ...

Comment: ... (only due to a bug, meaning that any block change around there would make it fall down and take me with it) and as if that all wasn't enough, there is also a gigantic lava ocean below me, with almost no chance to escape even if I was in better shape. So if this screenshot wasn't staged, I would be only a few seconds away from being pummeled, falling or burning to death, starving or any other fun method of dying, all at once.

Comment: I think that the visible "Set own Gamemode to Survival mode" command text ruins the screenshot

Answer (score 4):

The classic Jurassic Park line should tell you all you need to know in [battleblock-theater](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battleblock-theater)
[image]

Answer (score 4):

[xcom-chimera-squad](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xcom-chimera-squad)

The problem with recruiting snake people into your police force is that *leg*work might be a bit more difficult for some than others.

[image]

Comment: What game is this?

Comment: In addition to adding the game tag, I'd suggest adding description to why it's a moment before disaster. Not really sure what I'm looking at to be honest

Comment: Never skip leg day. Not having legs is not an excuse.