# Screenshot of the Week Contest #12

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15042) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15111)*

---

Welcome to the twelfth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Ronan's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15043/) of an impending tarantula attack in [animal-crossing-new-horizons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-crossing-new-horizons) took the first spot with 22 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question. After a few clarifications on previous competitions, we've compiled this handy list of requirements, so please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-05-11, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-05-18, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

---

## Theme

There is no theme for this week's contest, so go ahead and submit your best for this week!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: Can we quickly change this contest theme to Star Wars, since it's May the 4th?

Comment: @arghtype While I personally like that idea, series-specific themes were discouraged early on to give everybody a fair chance to post a submission.

Comment: I still stand behind my opinion that series non-specific themes are best, but perhaps there's room for Star Wars. That is the one series that has games on practically every single platform going back as early as the [Atari 2600](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Empire_Strikes_Back_(1982_video_game)) and more games coming out all the time. Even some games that aren't directly "Star Wars" have references to it with quotes, character dialog, cosmetics, etc... With at least a previous week's notice, I think it would be doable next year.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's really hard to take the handler seriously when she's wearing that palico costume.
[monster-hunter-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monster-hunter-world)

[image]

Comment: The world is full of mysteries to costume us.

Answer (score 14):

A green sunrise in the deserts of Calidor, in [astroneer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astroneer)

[image: A green sunrise in the deserts of Calidor]

Answer (score 13):

I somehow managed to capture this in [final-fantasy-7-remake](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-7-remake)

[image: Fiery Tornado]

Comment: Now that's a good one.  Desktop background worthy.

Comment: @TimmyJim Thanks! :) A friend of mine thought it was a promotional image when he first saw it

Answer (score 12):

A useful response from [superhot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superhot) to send people
[image]

Comment: Yep, this goes in the meme repository, thanks! :)

Comment: I also like https://xkcd.com/no.

Answer (score 9):

[call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2)

That's gonna be a blast... literally.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Rare footage: Republic Fleet bombards Star Forge station during the Battle of Rakata Prime, circa 3956 BBY.

[image]

[star-wars-kotor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-kotor)

Comment: That's one powerful fart

Answer (score 8):

Until version 1.12 of [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition), there was an achievement "When pigs fly" for falling off a cliff while riding a pig. But that's just falling, my pig can actually fly:

[image: when pigs fly upwards]

I did this by summoning a pig that was riding an XP orb. When I sat on it, the XP orb tried to get to me, which lifted the pig, which lifted me, which prevented the XP from reaching me, so it continued to fly upwards and so did we.

If you want to do this yourself, fly upwards a bit in Creative mode or stand on an edge with space below, run this command and mount the pig:

```
/summon experience_orb ~ ~-3 ~ {Passengers:[{id:"pig",Saddle:1}]}
```

Comment: I've never seen this done with a pig riding an xp orb, I have seen a pig riding a bat. This is clever

Comment: You have a very good imagination. I never would have thought to do that. Keep up the good work.

Comment: @LoreFriendly I think that idea originally came from somewhere else, but that was many years ago, so I don't remember anymore where it was. But yes, I have quite some imagination, one of my favourite applications of that on this site was [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/321540/171580). And of course it's useful in my longer programming answers, most of which depend on one idea to make the process possible or much easier, for example [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/352569/171580) I used a completely different approach than what the asker had in mind to get the result.

Answer (score 7):

just hanging out in [snowrunner](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snowrunner), you know

[image: a Fleetstar Scout 800 on its back in a mud puddle]

Comment: Bring clean socks.

Comment: Quite a lack of snow for a game called **Snow**runner

Answer (score 6):

Social distancing.

[image]

[assassins-creed-unity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-unity)

Comment: If I was given that look, I'd keep my distance regardless of the circumstances

Comment: I think he's trying to Force Grip me, actually.

Answer (score 6):

One from [a while ago](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/229066/28182), almost filling the whole roof with plants in [plants-vs-zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plants-vs-zombies):

[image: Pogo Party Final Wave]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Refunct]
Refunct

Comment: Hi @anisanwesley, submissions in this one closed last week, and voting closed a few hours ago. [We do have a new screenshot contest for this week up now](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15111/screenshot-of-the-week-13-residence) with a theme of "residence", and we'll probably do another unthemed contest in 2 weeks