# Screenshot of the Week Contest #13: Residence

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15079) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15134)*

---

Welcome to the thirteenth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Booga Roo's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15084/143571) of an unfitting character costume in a cutscene in [monster-hunter-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monster-hunter-world) took the first spot with 18 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question. After a few clarifications on previous competitions, we've compiled this handy list of requirements, so please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-05-25, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-06-01, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

---

## Theme

The theme for this contest is "Residence". So go ahead and build housing you're proud of, then show us the results!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: This should be a good one! By the way,  will advance notice of themes be continued in the future?

Comment: Not a valid submission, but someone built a "starter dirt… castle" in the first episode of a YouTuber/streamer server: https://img.youtube.com/vi/xZlqmUmaWuM/maxresdefault.jpg (copy of my comment [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes#comment44883_15045))

Comment: @BoogaRoo Generally we've been trying to pick the highest voted themes from the answers to the suggestion question, but it's true that it'd be nice to have some advance notice when trying to go for a specific theme. Maybe the start of the voting period of a themeless contest would be a good time to provide the theme for the following week's contest.

Comment: Advanced notice, pffft. If I had thought about it longer I would've come up with a 6yo [screen shot of Kilgore's base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpfPb.jpg) (language warning) that I took. (the administrator of Fonline Reloaded, a reverse engineered version of Fallout1&2 making it into a MMORPG). The only things put there by the server are the trees and the building.

Comment: I'm surprised that nobody submitted a Minecraft base. A ton of those are amazingly detailed and gigantic. I couldn't submit my ones, because most of them just look like collections of machines with a storage system, because… well, they are. :D I don't really build bases in Minecraft.

Comment: @FabianRöling A problem with most of my Minecraft bases is they don't really have a good angle that shows off what's great about them. My most recent one was underground with a big 'aquarium wall' facing the ocean. From ground level, all you could see was a trap door, but it contained multiple plant farms, a tree farm built into an underground gorge, menageries for animals, and so on. Would be great for a walk-through, but a single screenshot would leave too much to be desired. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In a post-apocalyptic world, its good to have a bunker base to keep the zergs out. [rust](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rust)

[image: Giant castle fortress]

Comment: Wow... that's one big base. I'm even too stupid to find eough food without getting killed.

Comment: @dly I actually play on a PVE server so I can build ridiculous things like this. Its completely vanilla (no increased resource gains), and we have a purge the last day before wipe where everyone can PVP and almost everyone gets raided. My base was 1 of 2 that didnt get raided.

Comment: Oh, that's a great idea. Not worrying about other players is a big deal for beginners like myself.  I'll look for a PVE server then :D

Answer (score 11):

Home is where you make it. [fallout-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-4)

[image]

Answer (score 8):

After years of investing so much time in the construction of homes in a wide variety of games, it's strange how few of them I was able to actually retrieve. And how unimposing they've become.

Well, here's something most [fallout-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-4) players should be able to relate to: I incorporated the viaduct into Greygarden.

[image]

Comment: Relate to? I'm not 100% sure that isn't one of mine. None of my shots are SFW. If more people experienced F4 the way I do, they wouldn't have any problem *not* leaving their house.

Comment: It took me some settlement building mods to realize that you can build on top of that highway.

Answer (score 7):

Home is where you store all your loot. And also where you can play video games safely.

[image: pocketdimension]

[dungeons-of-dredmor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-of-dredmor)