# Screenshot of the Week Contest #14

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15111) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15164)*

---

Welcome to the fourteenth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Dragonrage's base](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15117) in [rust](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rust) took the first spot with 14 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question. After a few clarifications on previous competitions, we've compiled this handy list of requirements, so please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-06-08, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-06-15, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

---

## Theme

There is no theme for this week, so go ahead and submit the best screenshot you've got!

Our next contest will have a '90s theme (games released 1990-1999, no remasters!), so go ahead and dust off some older titles to get ready for the next one!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This spent bullet cartridge was on its way to my face as I checked my Pip-boy in [fallout-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-4)

[image: Fallout 4 - cartridge being expelled]

Answer (score 9):

So simple and so beautiful

[image]

[journey](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/journey)

Comment: What game is this?

Comment: @Robotnik https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_(2012_video_game)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I just noticed the tag under the picture haha :)

Answer (score 7):

[counter-strike-source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-source) is too young for the 90s contest, but for some warm-up I digged up an old project of mine. I've ported several maps and scenarios from [command-and-conquer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer) to CS:S.

This is Renegade's fully functional Hand of Nod:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I did not expect to get a pet this early in [oldschool-runescape](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oldschool-runescape).

For some context, I quested my mining level up to about 35. At my level at Motherlode Mine, there was about a 1/246,300 chance of getting the pet.

[image: "You have a funny feeling like you're being followed. Contratulations, you've just advanced your Mining level. You are now level 37."]

Comment: At those odds do you ever wonder if you had bought a lottery, you could have won? :P

Comment: @LoreFriendly This account is so spoonfed, I got a 1/1,000 drop that I needed from a minigame the other day too. I wasn't even going for it, I just wanted to get 1 game done. Now I don't need to grind out that minigame.

Answer (score 6):

I started mapping in Hammer after I was blown away by the Half-Life demo in 1998/1999, and only really stopped making weird unplayable maps around 2014. Although the engine is dated, it was a great introduction to game design.

This was a map titled *The Void* - rendered in the [half-life-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-life-2) Source version (slightly enhanced using GeForce Experience) - in which the player would suddenly find himself ahead of the regular playing map, where it was still in construction.

This is from before the whole The Stanley Parable meta-gaming fad.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just some undead dogs standing sideways. And a floating chicken showing its (back then missing) neck. No unusual sight in my test worlds.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Do you like pumpkins? Here is my pumpkin patch in [rust](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rust) There are a total of 1296 plants here, each of which produce 5 pumpkins, for a total yield 6480 pumpkins.

[image]

Comment: That's totally normal in Minecraft. :D

Comment: Oh my gourd....

Answer (score 4):

[blade-and-soul](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blade-and-soul) is a game that never disappoints. And this character isn't feeling so good ...

[image: Vanishing character]