# Screenshot of the Week Contest #15: '90s

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15134) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15185)*

---

Welcome to the fifteenth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Robotnik's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15140/143571) of an errant spent cartridge in [fallout-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-4) took the first spot with 11 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question. After a few clarifications on previous competitions, we've compiled this handy list of requirements, so please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-06-22, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-06-29, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

---

## Theme

The theme for this contest is "'90s". Show us your best screenshots of games released between 1990 and 1999, no remasters!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: It'd be remiss of me to not post a Sonic game, wouldn't it?

Comment: My backups don't go back far enough for that :(

Comment: This one was hard, I think the only games I can screenshot that qualify are Sonic games

Comment: I ended up getting my screenshot from the games available in the [Sega Mega Drive & Genesis Classics](https://store.steampowered.com/app/34270/SEGA_Mega_Drive_and_Genesis_Classics/) pack on Steam, for anyone looking for inspiration

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [sim-ant](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sim-ant) named the best simulation game ever in 1992. Originally released in 1991, re-released in 1993 and again in 1996 for windows 95. I had a ton of fun playing this back in the day, and after I tired of playing as an ant, I also liked playing as a spider and eating as many ants as I could.

[image: sim ant]

Answer (score 12):

[image: screenshot of Dr. Robotnik in Sonic Adventure]

The mod team has a brief discussion ([sonic-adventure](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sonic-adventure))

Comment: This guy seems on the level, we should definitely listen to what he has to say

Comment: @Robotnik i refuse to listen to a guy who calls himself Dr Eggman

Comment: it would be hard to compete with the greatest scientific genius in the world in this contest :(

Comment: @Memor-X To be fair, [Robotnik wanted a different nickname](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdsaHO-nUG4)

Comment: Which is way different from [his take in Sonic Adventure 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4mPkze9AEs) (sadly released 2001 otherwise that'd be the one to pick). Then again, this boss form is called Egg Hornet and his ship is the Egg Carrier so I guess he's embraced it in this game too.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

> "Well Done"

[earthworm-jim-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earthworm-jim-2)

Answer (score 9):

[comix-zone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comix-zone)

I was brutally beaten in this game as a kid, launched it today with all my years of experience, nope, still got destroyed.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

*Scorpius, the boss of nightmares.*

From [sonic-spinball](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sonic-spinball) for the [sega-mega-drive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sega-mega-drive), released in 1993. I played this and other Sonic games at 6 years old, and this boss gave me nightmares. To get the full experience, [listen to the sounds it makes!](https://youtu.be/SqR23N_2AQA?t=87) Holy Moly!

[image: Scorpius Boss]

Answer (score 9):

The most satisfying moment in [dune-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-2), one of the best early 90s RTS games.

[image: Noooo!]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Legend of Dragon Boss Battle]

from [legend-of-dragoon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-of-dragoon) which, while released in the US on June 13, 2000, was release in Japan on December 2, 1999

this boss is featured in a PS1 Demo Disk (i believe it was Demo One) which i replayed over and over until i got the full game years later. the main difference between the Demo and Full versions of the game with this boss is that in the Demo you had Shana's, Dart's and Lavitz's Dragoons which made this phase of the boss alot easier as Dragoons can fly so their physical attacks can hit