# Screenshot of the Week Contest #16

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15164) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15204)*

---

Welcome to the sixteenth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Dragonrage's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15174/8350) of some ants in [sim-ant](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sim-ant) took the first spot with 14 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question. After a few clarifications on previous competitions, we've compiled this handy list of requirements, so please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-07-06, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-07-13, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

---

## Theme

There's no theme for this contest, but the theme for next contest will be [Victory](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15060/8350), as suggested by [Booga Roo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/136881/booga-roo).

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Wherein my ship begins going to space prior to disconnecting in [sea-of-thieves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-of-thieves)

Answer (score 7):

Planetrise (Giant's Deep) pictured from the surface of The Interloper in [outer-wilds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outer-wilds)

[image: Planetrise]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Yea, same here [hue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hue)

Answer (score 5):

I was going to put this [uniracers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uniracers) screenshot up last contest, but I guess it'll serve for this week. In the game options you can rename characters and the game has a list of forbidden words. Some of the words were predictable, but this one was my favorite.

[image: Uniracers SEGA screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

This is what happens in [blade-and-soul](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blade-and-soul) when you use d912pxy for the first time:

[image: d912pxy]

There's nothing wrong with it... Just a floating head on the left, see-through trees and landscape and really dark overall.

(For the curious: this is in Moonwater Plains - Misty Woods - Watchtowers)

Answer (score 4):

[assassins-creed-brotherhood](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-brotherhood)

[image: Assassin's Creed Botherhood]

You'd think at some point, with all those dead bodies around, one of those guards would get the idea that maybe Ezio Auditore da Firenze should be left alone

Comment: Well there is the one in the background that seems to think so.

Answer (score 3):

Running with my D-Dog, at night obviously because I've bought that useless night vision kit [metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

*Soldier dancing with Bazooka*

[image: Soldier dancing with Bazooka]

from [team-fortress-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2)

Answer (score 0):

Byleth ain’t messing around in [super-smash-bros-ultimate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-smash-bros-ultimate)

[image: Byleth special attack]