# Screenshot of the Week Contest #17: Victory

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15185) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15231)*

---

Welcome to the seventeenth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Unionhawk's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15186/127901) of a flying ship in [sea-of-thieves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-of-thieves) took the first spot with 8 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question. After a few clarifications on previous competitions, we've compiled this handy list of requirements, so please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-07-20, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-07-27, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

---

## Theme

The theme for this contest will be [Victory](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15060/8350), as suggested by [Booga Roo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/136881/booga-roo).

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: Are we keeping a tally of who won how many weekly contests? A gaming site needs a leaderboard. :-P

Comment: @LoreFriendly no, not current;y, but we do have a [hall-of-fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame)

Comment: Well that is good. So far many people are tied with two wins.

Comment: When I heard of the theme, I tried for a while to recreate something so that I would be able to post my own screenshot, but I couldn't do it. So I'll link it in the comments instead: You can die in the credits of Super Mario Galaxy 2: https://youtu.be/swdVIHQVBS4?t=26 This would have been an awesome submission, because it does indeed show victory, but also a "game over" screen at the same time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is Link's victory pose as he earns the fully restored power of the Master Sword. Just finished the "Trial of the Sword" yesterday in [zelda-breath-of-the-wild](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-breath-of-the-wild).

[image]

Answer (score 11):

*TIME*

From my first [night-in-the-woods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/night-in-the-woods) any% World Record

[image: Final credits of Night in the Woods, speedrun timer at 2:13:01. World Record is 2:13:56 by BearAbou.]

Answer (score 9):

Many years ago, I played a perfect 50-0 match in [halo-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halo-3) Team Slayer.

Two friends and I created a mini clan just for fun out of 1 month Xbox Live trails. Little did we know our smallest accounts would hold our biggest triumph.

[image: Halo 3, 50-0]

Comment: reminds me of my Halo CE days. ill have to try and dig up a screenshot from back then

Comment: "xDahSicKsnipERx", also known as: "the maximum amount of cliches that you can fit into a username character limit"

Comment: @FabianRöling While also being unoriginal with adding x at the beginning and end of the username

Answer (score 7):

After two wins and two losses in a best of five, this was the game that got me to diamond in [league-of-legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends) for the first time back in 2015.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I finished Twin Dragonriders boss battle in [dark-souls-2-sotfs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls-2-sotfs) by killing both of them with the single strike, you can see them vanishing:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Me beating the newest monster, Alatreon, in [monster-hunter-world-iceborne](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monster-hunter-world-iceborne), by myself, under 15 minutes.

[image: Alatreon is dead]

Comment: Now THAT is what I call a victory

Answer (score 6):

A perfect first round in [counter-strike-source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-source).

In order to get 8 points you need to kill the entire enemy team and defuse the bomb, which obviously is very rare.

This one happened over 10 years ago in a 5on5 league:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Just training my various Link Amiibo in [super-smash-bros-ultimate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-smash-bros-ultimate)

Answer (score 5):

> [image: defeating-isshin]

Defeating the final boss

> Isshin Sword Saint

in [sekiro-shadows-die-twice](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sekiro-shadows-die-twice) in my first playthrough.

Answer (score 4):

beating the final boss in [digital-devil-saga](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-devil-saga) (spoilered for those who don't want it spoiled)

> [image: Harihara's death]

> a triumph as while i have faced my fair share of Final Boss's Final Forms, some with annoying instant Death attacks, Harihara's final form threw a spanner in the works by having 6 elemental cores and gave Harihara a shield against the element they represent (making it immune to attacks) and each core had an attack so that gave the enemy turn 7 attacks, their attack order is random so you can't just go Absorb-Ice because last like Bufudyne was cast first. So in order to deal damage to Harihara you had to destroy the core of the element you attack with, **but at the start of the enemy turn, Harihara gets a free turn to resurrect a random core!**

Answer (score 4):

[image: lion dragon go boom boom]

Killing [monster-hunter-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monster-hunter-world)'s Teostra with the Switch Axe's Heavy Slam is a certain level of satisfaction. Getting a gem in your rewards is the cherry on top!