# Screenshot of the Week Contest #18

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15204) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15260)*

---

Welcome to the eighteenth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Booga Roo's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15213) of their completion of the Trial of the Sword in [zelda-breath-of-the-wild](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-breath-of-the-wild) took the first spot with 15 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question. After a few clarifications on previous competitions, we've compiled this handy list of requirements, so please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-08-03, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-08-10, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

---

## Theme

There is no theme for this week's contest, so go ahead and submit the best you've got!

Next contest's theme will be [Space Exploration](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15035), so make sure to go exploring to capture some amazing shots.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let everyone else kill each other. I'm enjoying a hot summer day in my pool in [rust](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rust).

[image]

Comment: Is that a kiddie pool visible also?

Comment: @LoreFriendly yep :D

Answer (score 10):

I cannot see a thing, but my hat is shiny!

[bloodborne](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bloodborne)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In April, I played around a lot with this amazing datapack for [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition): https://minecraft.plagiatus.net/article/minecraft-snapshot-20w14%E2%9C%A8

It has many hidden features, some of them activated by rare items in loot chests. So to find all of them, I filled a big area around me with these loot chests and then used a command to break all those chests at once.

Apparently that was not the best idea ever, because the game froze for multiple minutes on this frame:

[image]

[full resolution](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11VxO9NGUpJD6lnDhz_R8EO-BHMIMllea)

Comment: I cannot see your screenshot for some reason

Comment: @arghtype Someone had that issue before, it seemed to be a firewall issue. Maybe Dropbox is blocked for you?

Comment: Alright, now the embedded image is regularly inserted at half resolution and the full resolution link goes to Google Drive instead. That should hopefully work properly for everyone.

Answer (score 7):

An analysis of the plot of Alan Wake in a classroom of Riverport University in [quantum-break](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-break).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A rare Italian C.202EC stealth fighter from [war-thunder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/war-thunder)in vanta black paint.

[image: Flat black glitched Italian C.202EC fighter plane]

Comment: Every once in a while the game fails to load textures. Previous builds resulted in [lime green planes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hbjp.jpg), but this time it resulted in the ultimate night camouflage.

Comment: I had recently read about [Vanta Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantablack) being the blackest black. This is a better image than the one on Wikipedia to see it contrasted against other things.