# Screenshot of the Week Contest #19: Space Exploration

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15231) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15278)*

---

Welcome to the nineteenth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [dly's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15237/127901) of their relaxing summer day in the post apocalyptic world of [rust](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rust) took the first spot with 12 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question. After a few clarifications on previous competitions, we've compiled this handy list of requirements, so please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-08-17, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-08-24, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

---

## Theme

The theme for this week's contest is [Space Exploration](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15035), so make sure to go exploring to capture some amazing shots.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[super-mario-galaxy-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-galaxy-2)

Yoshi went to space, but his tongue didn't want to come along.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Two astro droids watching the world collapse in [star-wars-kotor-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-kotor-2)

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Drone spaceplane in orbit over Kerbin in [kerbal-space-program](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kerbal-space-program)

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Jebediah Kerman and Bob Kerman posing after landing on the Mun. Wish you were here!
[kerbal-space-program](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kerbal-space-program)

[image: Postcard from the Mun]

Comment: We choose to go the Mun to take pictures, as it turns out.

Answer (score 10):

Encountering a strange outpost at night in [no-mans-sky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-mans-sky)

[image: Encountering a strange outpost at night]

Answer (score 8):

[portal-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portal-2) spoiler

> [image]
>  SPAAAAACE

Answer (score 6):

Scenic planetfall ride above mars in [doom-eternal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doom-eternal)

[image: Mars Planetfall]

Answer (score 5):

Yesterday, I went to Hutton Orbital in [elite-dangerous](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elite-dangerous) for the first time and got myself a Hutton mug.

2 hours well spent.

[image: The Hutton mug.]

Answer (score 5):

Keeping those aliens out of the Harvester in [genesis-alpha-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genesis-alpha-one)

[image: Genesis Alpha One]

Answer (score 5):

Admittedly an older screenshot, but my proudest space exploration moment in [elite-dangerous](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elite-dangerous) nonetheless.

[image: Promotion to Elite in exploring]

Answer (score 5):

Exploring Earth Proxima in [warframe](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warframe)

[image]

Comment: Barely got it in, huh?

Comment: @Wrigglenite, just barely, was having issues getting the screen shot to upload for awhile. was too large