# Screenshot of the Week Contest #20

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15260) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15308)*

---

Welcome to the twentieth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Fabian Röling's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15266) of Yoshi's extendable tongue in [super-mario-galaxy-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-galaxy-2) took the first spot with 12 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question. After a few clarifications on previous competitions, we've compiled this handy list of requirements, so please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-08-31, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-09-07, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

---

## Theme

There is no theme for this week's contest, so go ahead and submit the best you've got!

Next contest's theme will be [Classic Games](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15067), so blow some dust off those old games and get ready to capture screenshots two weeks from now.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Admiring engineering in [borderlands-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-3)

[image: Heatant]

Answer (score 13):

The sculpture in front of the Palisade Property Bank in Prague in [deus-ex-mankind-divided](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deus-ex-mankind-divided) is such a haunting image.

[image]

Comment: I like this.  Very cool

Comment: I really do need to replay this game...

Answer (score 9):

My low settings aside, I'm still blown away by the areas with photogrammetry data in [microsoft-flight-simulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-flight-simulator). This is a screenshot of Kings Island as seen in a Cirrus SR22. There's some weirdness, for example, some of the steel roller coasters are replaced with large trees, since this sort of 3D reconstruction is primarily designed for buildings, but it's still very recognizably the park.

[image: Aerial view of Kings Island in the Cirrus SR22]

Comment: So how many FPS are you managing in the sim?

Comment: @LoreFriendly It depends on the area, average has been 15-20 which is not great not terrible. I'm looking to do a new build just like [everyone else](https://www.jonpeddie.com/press-releases/microsoft-flight-simulator-2020-will-stimulate-billions-of-dollars-in-pc-ga) though to stop getting the "your PC is below minimum requirements" message and get off minimum settings 720p

Comment: That sounds like a project gaming geeks would love to read about if/when you do that. :)

Answer (score 9):

Was just looking for the restroom in [paper-mario-the-origami-king](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper-mario-the-origami-king)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

*Josip Idromeno, at Mike's Bar, ca. 2008*

[far-cry-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/far-cry-2)

[image: Josip]

Comment: Ah, far cry 2... I remember going from Far Cry Instincts where you were some insane super beast character to some poor sap stuck in Africa who would keel over if he didn't take his malaria pill. Oh, and don't run out of those pills... they ain't easy to come by...

Comment: @TimmyJim yeah it was a weird transition for the series, but this game was still fun :)

Answer (score 7):

Performing Oliver's Ultimate, and Final Attack on the Forest Guardian in [ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch) (Remastered Version on Steam)

[image: Ni no Kuni]

Comment: [this is the boss theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AH2cGLtUfj0) which i feel just makes feel more epic

Answer (score 7):

BCAT

[guacamelee](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guacamelee)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I already shared a recent view of my chaotic [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) test world in [contest #7](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14946/171580). I also still have an older view of it in my collection, probably from 2016 or 2017:

[image]

There's barely anything in here that is also in the other screenshot, even though both show the area around 0 0. The test world just changes that much over time, because I put in no effort at all to preserve anything and just test things wherever I log in. That also means that I often don't move away from faraway places for weeks or months, making those yet another extremely crazy area full of chaos.

In this screenshot, I at least recognise some cut out shapes in the sandstone, the big stone platform in the middle with holes from a gigantic faraway explosion in it and a few lavafalls. The rail track on redstone block also existed back then already, but it was mostly overwritten or changed in other ways since then.