# Screenshot of the Week Contest #21: Classic Games

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15278) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15318)*

---

Welcome to the twenty-first edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [GnomeSlice's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15284) of marvelous engineering in [borderlands-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-3) took the first spot with 14 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-09-14, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-09-21, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

---

## Theme

The theme for this week's contest is [Classic Games](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15067), so dust off those older consoles and take a screenshot of a game released at least 10 years ago.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: Incidentally this would approximately be games released on or before [the beta launch of this site](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338/gaming)

Comment: Turns out minecraft counts! Just... very old minecraft.

Comment: @Corsaka https://classic.minecraft.net/

Comment: I just noticed that the requirement is 10+ years old games and the release date of Super Mario Galaxy 2 was in May 2010. So it actually qualifies. And I still play it, because it's still fun!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The opening sequence of [assassins-creed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed) (2007) never ceased to impress me[image]

Comment: I'm always so impressed with how much games have advanced in just over a decade

Comment: Was it really 2007 :O.... I feel old now.

Answer (score 13):

[half-life-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-life-2) is from 2004! It was insane jump in graphics since HL1, and this wall looks good even now:

[image: graffiti-in-hl2]

Comment: We don't go to Ravenholm...

Comment: No, Half life 2 is not from the year 533261680968262254540362294300681187196919596677805511775445400855553815370572071274134625024175008954367839937868813468681813094034303816007150212547811683755804358944845510090371213285728815067029776453419052916783813278662561690085648851670855547933642528031405475013517591711419220762313899522739255135157635954268784292059113129888274638523820593208262980673002254465674381742766473520819927119466341828506524368691016034370616907021636982485828621030975843682290936017888929968916545504819… Dammit, out of characters to write down 2004 factorial completely!

Answer (score 11):

Getting ready for the [psychonauts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychonauts) sequel

[image: People need their milk]

Comment: "I am a grieving widow!"

Comment: Am I missing some context here? Why is this so highly voted?

Comment: @FabianRöling It's all a conspiracy

Answer (score 4):

[final-fantasy-9](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-9) released 7 July 2000 (Screenshot taken from PC version released April 14, 2016)

That moment when you can't remember what level your characters are on

[image: Soulcage in Final Fantasy IX]

Answer (score 3):

Killing time during a boring lecture by browsing a Q&A site on your phone.

[little-busters](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/little-busters) (originally released in 2007)

[image]