# Screenshot of the Week Contest #22

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15308) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15342)*

---

Welcome to the twenty-second edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Riley's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15311) of the opening scene in [assassins-creed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed) took the first spot with 13 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-09-28, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-10-05, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured as the winner in the next Screenshot post.

---

## Theme

There is no theme for this week's contest, however, next week's theme is [water scenes as proposed by Booga Roo](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15057/127901).

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: Oh, the winner is now in a photo widget on the side! \o/

Comment: I was pleasantly surprised by the photo widget. That is great.

Comment: Lordran, is that you?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A view of San Francisco Bay from a tiny, rocky island. [watch-dogs-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watch-dogs-2)

[image: Watch Dogs 2 in-game photo of San Francisco Bay from an island]

Photo taken with the in-game camera. There’s nothing on this island but a tree and some shrubs, but I liked the framing the tree provided. In the distance you can see Alcatraz Island and the Golden Gate Bridge.

Answer (score 13):

My rocket made of salvage, taking off after restoring the landscape in [terra-nil](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terra-nil)

[image: Rocket Launch]

---

Terra Nil is a relaxing city-builder-esque game about ecosystem reconstruction. You turn desolate, toxic wastelands into thriving, living ecosystems, then - once the ecosystem can get by on it's own - salvage all your buildings to leave the area pristine.

It's a <strike>free</strike> *pay as much as you want* game, that was originally created for [Ludum Dare Game Jam #45](https://ldjam.com/events/ludum-dare/45/terra-nil-reclaim-the-wasteland), and I do highly recommend [checking it out](https://vfqd.itch.io/terra-nil).*

<sub>* Obligatory: I have no affiliation with this game.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for that screenshot and recommendation, I had some fun with this game. (it nearly feels like a reverse factorio ;) ).

Comment: @baudsp - no problem! Glad you enjoyed it. you're the second person to say it reminds them of factorio, I'm gonna have to give it a try :)

Answer (score 11):

Encountering a Sand Worm on <strike>Arrakis</strike> [osiris-new-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osiris-new-dawn)

[image: Sand Worm in Osiris New Dawn]

Answer (score 11):

One of my more aesthetically pleasing cities in [islanders](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islanders).

[image: Islanders]

Comment: That really does look good.

Answer (score 8):

Getting directions in [the-stanley-parable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-stanley-parable)

[image: adventure line]

Answer (score 8):

The luckiest drop I've ever gotten in [oldschool-runescape](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oldschool-runescape) - a 3 Kill count (KC) Corporeal Beast pet drop.  This is a 1 in 5000 drop chance.  If you don't know the game/boss, this particular drop is a really slow one to grind, because the Corporeal Beast is a slow boss to kill.  To get this at such an early KC is quite the accomplishment. As of February 2020, only 2,701 of these pets are in game.

[image: Pet]

This was also my first time ever killing the boss, and I kid you not, me and my friends in the picture were joking about the possibility of getting the pet that night.  Sure enough...

Comment: Also, peep my profile picture - you bet I'm flexing that pet!

Comment: According to the Old School Bot command `+drycalc 5000 3`, "You had a 99.94% chance of not receiving any drop, and a 0.06% chance of receiving at least one drop."

Comment: I just need to get another pet in the upcoming league to regain my dominance on pets submitted as a screenshot

Answer (score 8):

Game ads: ***Tactical Espionage Action***

Actual game:

[image]

[metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain)

Answer (score 6):

[image: Malik Sancho of Syria, trait: Crusader King (This is you)]

[crusader-kings-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusader-kings-3)

*points at the screen* That's the Crusader King

(this game has been wild, I started in the Iberian Peninsula, became the primary beneficiary of a crusade for Jerusalem, then again for a crusade for Syria, and now again a crusade for Galicia, the game giving me the option to swap to my dynasty's new king of those regions each time)

Answer (score 6):

The thumbnail of my [most recent stream highlight video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blpY1_YZYxg):

[image]

Oh no, I've made a horrible mistake…

(Warning: Swearing in that video.)

[minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition)

Comment: To anyone who hesitating to watch the video highlight: it's absolutely worth it.