# Screenshot of the Week Contest #23: Water Scenes

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15318) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15375)*

---

Welcome to the twenty-third edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Rory O'Kane's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15328) of San Francisco bay in [watch-dogs-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watch-dogs-2) took the first spot with 14 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-10-12, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-10-19, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's shiny new photo widget.

---

## Theme

The theme for this week's contest is [Water Scenes](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15057), so get ready to make a splash and take screenshots involving lots of water in some way.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: Last week's winner would've been great for this week :)

Comment: @Robotnik I keep getting confused when I see it in the sidebar!

Comment: The next contest's theme is not announced yet, can I suggest Halloween for obvious reasons? it was also suggested in themes question - https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15059/144891

Comment: My #19 picture is currently featured. Is that intended?

Comment: That's intended. We're using the voting period of new contests to feature the winners of contests from before we had the photo widget.

Comment: @FabianRöling - Yep, what Wrigglenite said. I started a post on the Hall of Fame to track which screenshots have been featured thus far: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15367/28182.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sunrise in [sea-of-thieves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-of-thieves)[image]

Answer (score 20):

I'm going to need a bigger boat... erm, maybe *any boat*.

[subnautica](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subnautica)

[image: Waterrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr]

Comment: Man, I still need to pick up that game

Comment: @SaintWacko I need to try sub-zero still.  Downloaded it a while ago when it first came out, but it kept crashing.  Wonder if its better now

Comment: @TimmyJim Last i saw, and played, subzero was in beta, and it was super broken. I'm guessing the game kind of half died, I couldn't continue the campaign because of a bug, and I left the game for months. Furthermore, they don't update the original anymore, so sadly it might be the end for those two games.

Comment: @MisterSirCode They're still working on it, but yes, it's in a buggy and unfinished state right now, which incidentally, was also how the original was made.

Answer (score 18):

I just finished the wonderful [abzu](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abzu): a game that shouldn't be left out of this week's theme.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic game, and I use the 'meditation' mode as a sort of virtual fishtank visual on screen whenever I host guests at home.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Cool idea!

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Calm of water...

(from [assassins-creed-origins](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-origins))

Answer (score 12):

Got photobombed by a fish in [genshin-impact](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genshin-impact)

[image]

Answer (score 11):

An early afternoon radstorm surrounding the coast of Far Harbor - [fallout-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-4)

[image: A green sky spans across the fog-covered sea. Lone ruins of a house can be traced out on a near, but barely visible island. A single blue light overlooks the dark coastline.]

Halloween is soon – maybe it's time to get lost in the gloomy, grim world of Fallout again :)

Answer (score 10):

Water lilies adorn this submerged temple in [the-witcher](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher).

[image: A look at a submerged temple in Witcher]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Zagreus overlooking the rivers of Asphodel]

Rivers of fire in [hades](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hades) is a type of water scene right?

Comment: look someone already submitted [tag:sea-of-thieves] ok

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Last moments above water in [bioshock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioshock)

Answer (score 7):

[image]

A shot of my [raft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raft) at night.

Answer (score 5):

Post-apocalyptic industrialization. This is about half of my setup for water purification to grow pumpkins in [rust](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rust).

[image: rust water pump farming]

Answer (score 4):

Tripitaka and Monkey admire a fish tank that survived the apocalypse in [enslaved-odyssey-to-the-west](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enslaved-odyssey-to-the-west).

[image]

Comment: I was torn between this scene where that little water means everything to the fish; or the late-game underwater stage which was visually more impressive. Enslaved: Odyssey to the West is an interestingly flavored adaptation of Journey to the West. Andy Serkis does a great job as the voice of Monkey.

Comment: This is an excellent and underrated game.  Memorable scene, and a good choice

Answer (score 4):

The great storm on Giants Deep is so mighty it can be captured from beneath the waves.

[outer-wilds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outer-wilds)

[image: Giants Depths]

Comment: Technically this was submitted after the deadline, but I was having dinner so it's probably fine.

Comment: Oh frig I literally did not even notice.  Busy week with the holiday and all for me this time around..

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Here you see a huge iceberg biome that fills up more than the entire server render distance. Just one thing is missing, hmmm… Oh right, it's the icebergs! I wonder where they went… Oh right, into my inventory! All of them!

The ice visible in this screenshot all generated over time around the path. Originally there was none there either.
I did actually build an AFK ice farm on this server, but it turns out that mining icebergs is much faster, because you don't need to wait for water to freeze and it's already at least packed ice, some of it even blue ice. So I mined a lot of ice for Nether tunnels. Eventually everything within render distance of that path (which is longer than what's visible here) was gone. If the server render distance was bigger, I would have mined out more, but for now 5 double chests of blue ice should be enough…

Comment: "should"

"enough"

Comment: Well, I did recently use up about 20 double chests full of stone bricks for Nether tunnels. And about one double chest of blue ice.