# Screenshot of the Week Contest #24: Halloween

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15342) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15393)*

---

Welcome to the twenty-fourth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [SaintWacko's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15344) of a sunrise on the [sea-of-thieves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-of-thieves) took the top spot with 19 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-10-26, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-11-02, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's shiny new photo widget.

---

## Theme

The theme for this week's contest is [Halloween](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15059), so go ahead and get some spooky screenshots for this special holiday edition of Screenshot of the Week!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Me and my Palico getting in the right mood for spooks. [monster-hunter-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monster-hunter-world)

[image: Spooky hunter and her Palico]

Answer (score 11):

Zombie Soldier is coming for you! [team-fortress-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2)

[image: Soldier on Mann Manor Event]

Answer (score 10):

Spooky ghost in [the-elder-scrolls-4-oblivion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-4-oblivion)

[image]

Answer (score 8):

"Hey, Elthon, looks like we chose the same costume!"

"Just watch it with that Igni sign around here, alright."

(From [the-witcher-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-2).)

[image: Geralt and Elthon in costumes]

Answer (score 8):

*In this town we call* [planetside-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planetside-2),
*Everyone hail to the pumpkin king*

[image]

Answer (score 5):

*Editor's note: we were playing this game at about 2:00 AM local time for me*

[image: screenshot of a ghost]

Mark Brown is here in [phasmophobia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phasmophobia). I don't think he enjoyed me being in his house given that he killed me about 5 minutes later.

I believe we have the transcript from that final hunt:

> "Oh god he's here. I'M DEAD I'M DEAD I'M DEAD I'M DEAD I'M DEAD I'M DEAD"

Comment: can confirm, the transcript is pretty accurate.