# Screenshot of the Week Contest #25

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15375) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15412)*

---

Welcome to the twenty-fifth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Wrigglenite's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15378) of spooky outfits in [monster-hunter-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monster-hunter-world) took the top spot with 13 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-11-09, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-11-16, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's shiny new photo widget.

---

## Theme

There is no theme for this week, so go ahead and submit whatever you want!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Flowers at night in [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn)

[image: The moon above the mountain]

Comment: Wow that is beautiful. I want to buy it, but was hearing the PC version had some issues. Is this on PC?

Comment: @LoreFriendly Nah PS4, although I'll probably end up getting it on PC too if it goes on sale. It's a great game, visually and story-wise :-)

Answer (score 9):

Chinatown in [genshin-impact](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genshin-impact)

[image: Genshin screenshot]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Ultra modded Skyrim SE - Distant Solitude visible from Morthal]

Ultra modded Skyrim SE - Distant Solitude visible from Morthal. Terrain LODs generated using xLodgen. Distant LODs using Dyndolod. ENB is Ljoss.

[skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim)

Answer (score 8):

The Imperial Clipper, one of the most luxurious ships ever built, touched down within alien ruins known as a Guardian Structure. Within the puzzle of the ruins lies mysterious alien technology that might be useful for defending against Thargoid incursions into human-inhabited systems in the Witch Head Nebula of [elite-dangerous](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elite-dangerous).

[image: An Imperial Clipper landed within a Guardian Structure]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

[popup-dungeon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popup-dungeon)

Comment: is "Remainder" a character name, a typo, or a joke here?

Comment: @Corsaka That's the name of the computer character in the corner.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Horrified ghosts look on as a fighter tug drives into space and over the nearby sun on the NSV13 server in [Space Station 13](https://spacestation13.com/).

Answer (score 5):

[mad-max](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mad-max) is coming for you...

[image: Coming for you]

Answer (score 5):

Mining isn't for everyone, but when the crystals light the cave just right...
[image: Crystal Caverns, Deep Rock Galactic]
[deep-rock-galactic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-rock-galactic)

Answer (score 4):

Spiral Abyss in [genshin-impact](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genshin-impact)

[image: Spiral Abyss]