# Screenshot of the Week Contest #26: Loading Screens

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15393) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15447)*

---

Welcome to the twenty-sixth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Robotnik's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15395) of a moonlit flower field in [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn) took the top spot with 13 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-11-23, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-11-30, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's shiny new photo widget.

---

## Theme

This week's theme is [Loading Screens](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15036), so get ready for a whole lot of waiting!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image: More than 40,000 Cessna 172s have been built since the model first flew in 1955.]

I love when loading screens hit me with cool facts about the world, and this cool fact about the Cessna 172 Skyhawk in [microsoft-flight-simulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-flight-simulator) is a good one.

Comment: Snowrunner is another really good game for this except instead of airplane facts you get trucking facts

Comment: This is a cool thing. The idea being that if the game is going to pull you out of the immersion for however small time, they might as well teach you something. RPG games tend to do this by sharing something about the game world.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Loading screen in [halo-the-master-chief-collection](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halo-the-master-chief-collection) are so pretty

Answer (score 10):

[image: Skyrim lore based loading screen]

The Elder Scrolls lore talk about the [Soul Burst](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Soulburst) that happened in the past. The default loading screens for [skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim) leave a lot to be desired, but modders have filled up the void nicely.