# Screenshot of the Week Contest #27

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15412) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15474)*

---

Welcome to the twenty-seventh edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Unionhawk's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15413) of a loading screen in [microsoft-flight-simulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-flight-simulator) took the top spot with 15 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-12-07, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-12-14, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme

There is no theme for this week, so go ahead and submit whatever you want!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: Seeing a few downvotes on submissions here, so as a reminder to voters: we only take **upvotes** into account when determining the winner for the screenshot competition :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[mortal-shell](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortal-shell)

[image]

Comment: Looks like he just sliced those towers with his sword and they're about to fall.

Answer (score 10):

[image]
A call for sanity from the orange residents in [supraland](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supraland)

Answer (score 9):

The Ommoran Heartstone has many defenses, but Doretta is up to the task!

Dwarves at work in [deep-rock-galactic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-rock-galactic):
[image: Ommoran Heartstone]

Answer (score 9):

*A confederacy of crunches* - [left-4-dead-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/left-4-dead-2)

[image: Confederacy of Crunches]

Comment: The achievement was actually to complete a campaign using only melee weapons, but the name of it seemed relevant to the scene

Answer (score 8):

Not wise to be outside during a Superheated Storm after the Origin update of [no-mans-sky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-mans-sky)

[image: No Man's Sky Superheated Storm in Origins]