# Screenshot of the Week Contest #28: Holiday

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15447) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15496)*

---

Welcome to the twenty-eighth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [arghtype's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15449) of their character weilding a large two handed sword in the middle of a ruined castle in [mortal-shell](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortal-shell) took the top spot with 13 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2020-12-21, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2020-12-28, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme

The season-appropriate theme for this week is **Christmas/Holiday**. We're looking for whatever the holiday season means to you, so give us the best seasonal content you have!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Management threatens to cancel the holidays if we don't stop kicking the decorations.
[image: Christmas in the Deep Rock Galactic space rig.]
Free beer at the bar in [deep-rock-galactic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-rock-galactic)

Answer (score 11):

Santa is busy this time of the year!

[death-stranding](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-stranding)

[image]

More and more games add Photo Modes nowadays, and that's awesome!

Answer (score 8):

Always efficient Ficsit has determined that employees need a minor break for improved overall productivity and thus the Ficsmas Holiday was born in [satisfactory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satisfactory). Here we have rows of of FICSMAS trees generating gifts to feed a production line producing various festive baubles. A space dropped giant gift from our generous employer has landed precariously on a conveyor merger. Don't worry, it's mostly bubble wrap.

[image: screenshot of ficsmas holiday in satisfactory]

Answer (score 6):

Celebrate the new year with FIREWORKS in [risk-of-rain-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/risk-of-rain-2)
[image]

Comment: Fireworks x 82 and Squid Turret x 29, wow! Too bad the final boss doesn't have any chests around...

Comment: Yea, I kept getting more in hopes the rusty box would spew enough to eventually reach him.  Did not work, but his stealing all of them was probably a disappointment.

Answer (score 6):

*It's winter time, around the year 2007.  You wake up one morning to see that school is closed because the night before there was a snow storm.  You hop onto your parents computer and open Internet Explorer and go to your favorite game.  You are greeted by this screen, and you know that you and your friends are about to have a good time.*

[image]

[oldschool-runescape](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oldschool-runescape) login screen, traditionally decorated for the holidays.

Answer (score 2):

It's christmastime in Gielenor, and even Frank, Darkmeyer's goodest boy, is getting into the holiday spirit in this [oldschool-runescape](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oldschool-runescape) holiday event.

[image]