# Screenshot of the Week Contest #29

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15474) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15511)*

---

Welcome to the twenty-ninth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Booga Roo's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15480) of some not too festive spirit in [deep-rock-galactic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-rock-galactic) took the top spot with 13 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-01-04, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-01-11, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme

There is no theme for this week, so go ahead and submit whatever you want!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image]

Hunting robots in [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn)

Comment: This game is just so beautiful. Nice action shot!

Answer (score 7):

[image: Desert Village at Night]

Never thought the view in [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) would be so nice! Finding this village in the middle of the night was especially magical.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Satisfactory]

The first morning light on "The Gold Coast" (The Islands) in [satisfactory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satisfactory) with my Oil refinery to the right

Answer (score 5):

Full moon over the rocky mountains in [microsoft-flight-simulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-flight-simulator)

[image: full moon over Telluride Airport in microsoft flight simulator]

Answer (score 4):

Does anything look weird in [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition)? Look closely:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you overlayed HD and SD textures? Why?