# Screenshot of the Week Contest #30: Game of the Year 2020

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15496) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15534)*

---

Welcome to the thirtieth edition of the Screenshot of the Week, and the first of 2021!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Batophobia's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15500) of robot hunting in [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn) took the top spot with 17 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-01-18, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-01-25, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme

Since it is the first contest of the new year, the theme for this week is **Game of the Year 2020**, so go ahead and submit a screenshot from your favorite game of 2020. We'll leave the meaning of "of 2020" up to you, whether it's your favorite release of the year or just the best one you played last year.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: Does WoW count with Shadowlands released in 2020?

Comment: I don't think I've played any 2020 games.  Lots of Overwatch, some single player (partial) replays, but nothing new.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A lot of [half-life-alyx](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-life-alyx) is beautiful, but the bottles just take the cake.

[image: A bottle in the light.]

Also, taking screenshots in VR is such a pain.

Answer (score 11):

@Wipqozn's dead body after he lost a foot race to a ghost in [phasmophobia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phasmophobia)

[image: Wipqozn's dead body in Phasmophobia]

Comment: Looks like he also lost an arm

Comment: Alt title: Wipqozn has too much to drink

Answer (score 9):

[image: Mass Effect 2 lair of the Shadow Broker]

A touching reunion between Fem-Shepard and her sweetheart Liara T'Soni in [mass-effect-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-2)'s DLC *Lair of the Shadow Broker* which I played for the first time in 2020

Comment: Oh god more mass effect please. Thanks for the memories.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Cell Games]
Love the art style in [dragon-ball-z-kakarot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-z-kakarot)

Answer (score 8):

2020 was a weird year for me, like, overall. But for my game of the year I think I have to consider overall impact on me/level of hyperfocus. So with that being said, my number 1 game of 2020 was [microsoft-flight-simulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-flight-simulator)

[image: Line of aircraft at KATL holding short of 27R on N, taxiing to the terminal]

Last year I got hyperfocused on flight simulation in part due to the pandemic, earning a VATSIM controller certification at the very end of the year (due to: VATSIM requires full real name I will not provide further details on this but it's been cool and fun and I'm working on upgrading my cert this year). This was in large part due to the release of MSFS 2020.

So, in that spirit, please find enclosed a screenshot of me in line to taxi to the terminal at Atlanta during today's event (I'm the properly rendered Delta A320neo in the middle). There was a lot of traffic in the air, but we all got through it in a safe and professional manner. Shoutouts to the controllers at Atlanta Virtual ARTCC for running a great event.