# Screenshot of the Week Contest #31

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15511) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15569)*

---

Welcome to the thirty-first edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [K00lman's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15527) of the bottle physics of [half-life-alyx](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-life-alyx) took the top spot with 11 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-02-01, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-02-08, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme

There is no theme this week. Go ahead and submit whatever you want!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What happens when you become the Emperor of Hispania in [crusader-kings-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusader-kings-3)?

You start to receive poetry from your adoring admirers, of course.

[image]

Comment: Hehe medieval pickup lines. Priceless.

Comment: Is it true, though? Addila doesn't look too shabby, but is she really twice as hot as Fernando's wife? Do you have a screenshot of the wife so we can compare?

Answer (score 8):

The Colonel's surprise redecorating of the home ship in [mothergunship](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mothergunship)

[image: Happy Birthday!]

Comment: Nice birthday. Where's the cake?

Answer (score 7):

[image]

As someone that really enjoyed the cartoon back in the day, [samurai-jack-battle-through-time](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samurai-jack-battle-through-time) is a lot of fun

Comment: is it just an arcade-y, "pick up and play for 20 minutes" kind of game? needing some more of those in my life...

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Some of the levels took a bit of time, but I'm the player that looks for the secrets.  I still don't think I would consider it for quick game sessions, but playing a level would probably take 10-30 minutes with cutscenes.

Answer (score 7):

How I feel about submission period for this contest

[the-surge-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-surge-2)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Some really good environmental storytelling in [umurangi-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/umurangi-generation). There's some other really good stuff in the DLC that I encountered today, but here's one from earlier in the game.

[image: I just wanted meaning in life yet here I am]

Answer (score 6):

The supply drop pilots pick the worst places to send supplies!
Treetop supply drop in [7-days-to-die](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7-days-to-die):
[image: Treetop supply drop in 7 Days to Die]

Answer (score 6):

*An island in progress* - [terra-nil](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terra-nil)

[image: An island in progress]

---

This was going to be my entry for Game of the Year 2020 but I ran out of time to capture and post the screenshot, so apologies in advance for the waffle below:

Terra Nil is a relaxing city-builder-esque game about ecosystem reconstruction. You turn desolate, toxic wastelands into thriving, living ecosystems, then - once the ecosystem can get by on it's own - salvage all your buildings to leave the area pristine.

Since the [last time](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15321/28182) I posted a Terra Nil screenshot the game (and the developers) have been [picked up by indie dev house *Free Lives*](https://vfqd.itch.io/terra-nil/devlog/188191/the-future-of-terra-nil) (you may know them as the team behind [broforce](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broforce) and [gorn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gorn)).

The current version of Terra Nil was originally created for [Ludum Dare Game Jam #45](https://ldjam.com/events/ludum-dare/45/terra-nil-reclaim-the-wasteland), and was featured in a few 'best games of 2020' articles and videos. If you want to check it out, it's <strike>free</strike> pay as much as you want [on itch.io](https://vfqd.itch.io/terra-nil).*

<sub>* Obligatory: I have no affiliation with this game.</sub>

<sup>Also, [wanna see how the island turned out?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6uOg.jpg)</sup>

Answer (score 6):

Life in a busy cave of [slime-rancher](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slime-rancher)'s Indigo Quarry.

[image: Slime Rancher screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

I remember seeing a video of a child jumping off a cliff and turning into a black bird. I thought of posting an ID question here, but a reverse image search gave a direct hit: [vane](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vane). The production design is beautiful.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Adet'pa, Klingon master spy, takes some time to relax with a Federation admiral under the supervision of the time monks. General Martok just likes to watch.

[image: Adet'pa makes out with a Federation admiral under the watchful eyes of the Klingon time monks. General Martok just likes to watch.]

Comment: What game is this?

Comment: @Joachim Star Trek Online.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Taol VS Zava]

Toal delivering the final blow (a Burst Attack) to Zava in [ys-origin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ys-origin)

Answer (score 3):

The progress on my city in [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition):

[image: My City]