# Screenshot of the Week Contest #32: Secrets and Easter Eggs

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15534) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15604)*

---

Welcome to the thirty-second edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Raven Dreamer's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15539) of a love letter in [crusader-kings-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusader-kings-3) took the top spot with 12 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-02-15, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-02-22, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme

This week's theme is [Secrets and Easter Eggs](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15068), so go search every nook and cranny!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: Historical fun fact: The first Easter Egg in a game was done by the game developer Warren Robinett in the game  "Adventure" (1980, Atari 2600). Back then, game developers were not included in the credits, so he secretly made a little hunt in the game that brought the player to a hidden room that simply displayed a message saying "Created by Warren Robinett".

Answer (score 15):

Actual Easter Eggs in [risk-of-rain-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/risk-of-rain-2)

[image]

Answer (score 11):

[image: The Legend of Heroes: Trails in the Sky Chat]

What do chests do when characters aren't looting them? one chest outside of Ruan in the Liberl Kingdom in [the-legend-of-heroes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-legend-of-heroes) [trails-in-the-sky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trails-in-the-sky) seems to have been watching [*Braveheart*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIvRkjOd1f8&t=2m14s)

Answer (score 9):

If you know, you know...  This little reference of an easter egg in [dusk](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dusk)

[image: The Duke of Dusk]

Comment: An easter egg of an easter egg...

Comment: @TimmyJim eggception?

Comment: @arghtype It's eggceptional!

Answer (score 8):

Totally working and not slacking off in [saints-row-the-third](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saints-row-the-third)

[image: Keyboard Cat]

Answer (score 7):

In [blade-and-soul](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blade-and-soul), inside the [Tomb of the Exiles](https://bladeandsoul.gamepedia.com/Tomb_of_the_Exiles) dungeon, on a room closed by a lever, you can find this reference to [Timon and Pumbaa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timon_and_Pumbaa), from the animated film ["The Lion King"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lion_King).

[image: Ti Mon and Pum Ba]

This room will usually be full of spiders, instead of Ti Mon and Pum Ba.
I would say it is roughly a 25% chance of spawning this easter egg.

They do have a few lines of text:

- Pum Ba: Why doesn't this open?!
- Pum Ba: I though I had the right key...
- Pum Ba: Stop! This treasure's mine! (under attack)
- Ti Mon: I though you said this was a sure thing!
- Ti Mon: Hurry! Forget about the treature! Go!
- Both: Dammit! I won't let them take my treasure.

The treasure chest opens by killing them, and has an incredibly low chance of giving an outfit.

Answer (score 4):

Just the Pokémon Dojo Master Mustard in [pokemon-sword-shield](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sword-shield) [pokemon-isle-of-armor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-isle-of-armor) playing [pokemon-quest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-quest) on his Nintendo Switch.

[image: Mustard playing Pokémon Quest]