# Screenshot of the Week Contest #33

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15569) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15641)*

---

Welcome to the thirty-third edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [arghtype's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15573) of actual easter eggs in [risk-of-rain-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/risk-of-rain-2) took the top spot with 15 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 00:00 UTC of 2021-03-02, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 00:00 UTC of 2021-03-09, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme

There is no set theme this week, so go ahead and submit whatever you want!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I recently finished the [shadow-of-the-colossus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadow-of-the-colossus) remaster. I never played the original on PS2, but bluepoint did a beautiful job on the look of the game.

[image]

Comment: This would have been an amazing entry for the "Scenery" theme (which my submission for SotC won :) )

Comment: @Wondercricket sad that I missed it, just recently played through it :(

Comment: Better late than never! Even after 16 years, still one of my favorite games

Comment: i kind of want to go back to the ps2 version and find the same spot, see what it used to look like

Answer (score 12):

A majestic flyby of a ringed planed in [elite-dangerous](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elite-dangerous)

[image: A ringed planet in the sun with the planet casting a shadow on the ring.]

Comment: Awesome capture

Answer (score 10):

Special delivery!
[image: Special delivery!]
I sent a surprise gift to a fighter that survived a rough landing on his airfield in [war-thunder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/war-thunder).

Answer (score 9):

Lovin' the Ghibli in [ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch) [image]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Creeper inside our house]

One of my friends brought home a weird looking dog in [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition)

Comment: Yes we have like 10 beds in the corner. Yes somebody died and then instantly exploded.

Comment: Damn, at least you guys have a cool home.

Comment: Eating seeds as a pastime activity?

Answer (score 6):

Yet another post apocalyptic world to explore

[code-vein](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-vein)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Death Stranding]

Pushing the Reverse Trike's battery to it's limit for that last drop off [death-stranding](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-stranding)

Answer (score 4):

Well this could've been put in [#32](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15569/screenshot-of-the-week-contest-32-secrets-and-easter-eggs) but it just happened now in [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition).

[image: San Andreas?]

Comment: Wiki explanation: "A reference to the mission 'Wrong side of the tracks' in Grand theft auto San Andreas." Yeah… I still don't get the joke.

Comment: All we need to do, is follow the damn train, CJ!

Answer (score 2):

> "*Thereupon Isabella took Edward's glistening visage in her hand and embraced his icy lips, which were twisted into a cynical grin.*"

Hmm. Sounds familiar? [the-witcher-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-3)'s *Moribundia* was totally ripped off by Stephenie Meyer.

[image]