# Screenshot of the Week contest #34: Winter

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15604) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15682)*

---

Welcome to the thirty-fourth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Kaizerwolf's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15606) of abandoned temple ruins in [shadow-of-the-colossus-2018](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadow-of-the-colossus-2018) took the top spot with 15 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-03-15, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-03-22, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme

This week's theme is [Winter](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15037), so go get some screenshots of wintery goodness before Spring officially arrives!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: As I'm in upside-downland, can I submit pictures of summer instead? :P

Comment: @Robotnik I laughed much harder than I should’ve at that comment

Comment: i wish i was far enough in valheim to make a cool house in the mountains/snow, but no such luck

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Enjoying frozen dam view in [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn)

[image]

Comment: i want to replay this game, but i also feel it was better as a one time experience. i collected and completed absolutely everything, it almost feels like going back would sully my experience

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I've played the story through its entirety three times. I can agree on some games being a one-time experience, however one of my favorite things to do is re-play through a game (albeit a few months/years later) and seeing story elements from a different perspective that's only revealed after completing it once

Comment: The story and visuals are great, but as a bit of a closet completionist the collecting and points of interest in H:ZD are a little overwhelming. I think I'll complete it 100% once, and then probably never again XD

Answer (score 15):

I live in a place that does not get any snow, despite my love for it, so I made a little snow cabin in [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition)

[image: My cabin in the snow.]

This was built in and for VR, but I'm lazy so you get a flatscreen screenshot.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

A cozy cottage on Skellige.

[the-witcher-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-3)

Answer (score 10):

It's MAR10 day, but the penguin's aren't too impressed in [super-mario-64](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-64)
[image]

Comment: MAR10 upvotes! Woo!

Answer (score 6):

[image: double rainbow over a snowy ramp in Burlington, VT]

Spring isn't for another week, and up here in Burlington, VT, we have a nice snowy ramp and a double rainbow in [microsoft-flight-simulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-flight-simulator).

Answer (score 2):

Before I placed any torches, my iron farm in [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) looked like a Mario level.

[image: lava and snow]

(Mario games do this all the time, examples: [Shiverburn galaxy](https://www.mariowiki.com/Shiverburn_galaxy), [Freezeflame galaxy](https://www.mariowiki.com/Freezeflame_galaxy), [Hot and cold collide](https://www.ign.com/wikis/super-mario-galaxy/Hot_and_cold_collide), [Hot & cold](https://www.mariowiki.com/Hot_%26_cold), [Meltdown mayhem](https://www.mariowiki.com/Meltdown_mayhem), …)