# Screenshot of the Week Contest #35

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15641) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15718)*

---

Welcome to the thirty-fifth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [arghtype's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15642) of a frozen dam in [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn) took the top spot with 20 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-03-29, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-04-05, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme

There is no theme this week, so go ahead and submit the best you have!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Flight of flamingos over Memphis (Egypt) in [assassins-creed-origins](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-origins)

[image]

Comment: Before I even noticed they were flamingos, they looked like a man flipping over. +1 for that.

Answer (score 13):

View on the wetlands south of Benek in southeast Velen (or a [Van Ruisdael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_van_Ruisdael)).

[image]

[the-witcher-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-3)

Comment: Sorry if this is a newbie question but how did you hide Geralt?

Comment: @LoreFriendly I use [Nvidia Ansel](https://www.nvidia.com/geforce/geforce-experience/ansel/). With certain supported games like this one, you are able to 'launch a camera' from the avatar's position, and simply go anywhere in the game world (whereas Kingdom Come: Deliverance, for example, limits the camera's movement). Often NPCs are not loaded beyond a certain area around the avatar, so here, judging by the presence of the deer, Geralt is somewhere beneath the camera, or hidden behind a tree or bush.

Comment: That is cool. I will check it out right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Lady Liberty's new home in [animal-crossing-new-horizons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-crossing-new-horizons)

[image: Lady Liberty above a waterfall]

Comment: America, is that you?

Answer (score 8):

Riding through early morning mist in Red Dead Redemption 2.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I put blocks of sand in cobweb in [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) and it looks very ridiculous. Tried the same with concrete powder in water with soul sand in the bottom.

[image: Concrete Powder Mix]

I guess that explains the destroyed powder on the ground.

Comment: What the textures on the side are doing is called [Z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) (no matter if it's the Z coordinate or anything else).

Answer (score 4):

[image: "I don't know how you can say that. Although I will admit that the possibility of a Resonance Cascade scenario is extremely unlikely... I just don't feel comf--"]

I've been playing through [black-mesa](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-mesa) and I think this is technically foreshadowing.

Comment: These lines (well, of the original) keep popping up in my head every now and then :)

Comment: now that xen is done, i really gotta go back to black mesa. such a faithful recreation of HL1, which i can't stand to play lol

Comment: Oh god, please not.

Answer (score 4):

Enjoy the sunset in [sea-of-thieves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-of-thieves)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Starry night over evil guys castle in [moss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moss). It's really cool to see scenes like this in VR

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: 'tea' in polite company]

[the-legend-of-heroes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-legend-of-heroes) [trails-in-the-sky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trails-in-the-sky) after a run in with drunk Duke Dunan.