# Screenshot of the Week Contest #36: Giant Monsters

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15682) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15753)*

---

Welcome to the thirty-sixth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Marc_Alx's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15687) of a group of flamingos in [assassins-creed-origins](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-origins) took the top spot with 14 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-04-12, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-04-19, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme

The theme for this week is **giant monsters**, so give us your biggest, most fearsome screenshot you can find this week!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: How was last week's winner decided? Both top answers had 13 votes when the contest ended. Is it determined by the first vote that tips the balance?

Comment: @Joachim If there's a tie when we're writing up the new post then the team usually just casts a tiebreaking vote which is what I did.

Comment: Any time i get close to one of the giant creatures in Subnautica for a pic, I chicken out and swim away :(

Comment: Nooo, I missed it! I had the perfect screenshot prepared for this. :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to look pretty close to see my ship!

[image]

<sup>It's an Asteroid Larvae anomaly from [no-mans-sky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-mans-sky)</sup>

Comment: ..and this is only the larva. Yikes.

Answer (score 10):

An angry Rajang about to eat my face in [monster-hunter-rise](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monster-hunter-rise).

[image: rajang]

**Disclaimer:** *No electric gorillas were harmed in the making of this photo, but the photographer certainly was.*

Comment: *one electric gorilla may have been harmed after the making of this photo

Comment: Not exactly giant, but it'll do

Answer (score 8):

Okay Arqade, I DID THIS FOR YOU.

[subnautica](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subnautica) is terrifying sometimes.

[image]

Comment: I've heard the sea creatures in subnautica were scary, but I was not expecting that

Comment: @Wondercricket the in-game description for them is, in short, "underdeveloped brain, mainly muscle, bones, teeth, and rage"

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r0Hicc6ZvPs

Comment: Since meeting those Reaper Leviathans up close, I am not *that* scared anymore of anything else in the game. Only recently I went below 900 meters, and met (one of) the Sea Dragon Leviathan(s), which seemed almost silly in comparison (might have to do with the fact it kept swimming inside solid rock). Anyway, you did it! :)

Answer (score 6):

Ruckus (my Vermling Mindthief) got caught at the wrong end of a corridor this week, with two large Earth Demons towering over him.

[image: Ruckus flanked by two large earth demons]

*(Gloomhaven in [tabletop-simulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tabletop-simulator))*

Comment: Not sure if this counts as "Giant Monsters" - the sense of scale kinda gets lost a bit with tokens.

Answer (score 6):

An epic creature that just killed all my pals in [spore](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spore)

[image: An epic creatre]

Answer (score 6):

The Doom Slayer retrieving his Crucible from the corpse of a massive Titan in the city of Taras Nabad in [doom-eternal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doom-eternal).  If you squint you can see him.

[image: Retrieving the crucible]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Adamantoise in Final Fantasy XIII]

the Pulse l'Cie fighting an Adamantoise in Eden in [final-fantasy-13](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-13) with Vanille trying to cheap shot it with Death, Lightning doing some impressive aerial acrobatics and Sazh wasting time after casting Haste

Comment: Man... Despite the reputation FF13 got, this brings back memories. When the Adamantoise becomes more difficult on Grand Pulse, I spent a few days fighting that thing trying to get the related trophy. The final fight went on for 2.5 hours. It wasn’t until after I beat it did I learn it was susceptible to Death...

Comment: @Wondercricket i remember when first playing beating an Adamanchelid in Eden as the mandatory fight there and feeling i could now kill any of them i charged against the Adamantoise here thinking it was the same and not only bring surprised by it being bigger but also being deadlier, and then when i got back to Grand Pulse seeing that there was 2 types

Answer (score 6):

Encountering the fiend Morvudd in Boxholm on Ard Skellig.

[image]

[the-witcher-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-3)

Answer (score 6):

Our Lady of the Charred Visage in [blasphemous](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blasphemous)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

When it comes to giant, definitely can't leave out the titans of [xenoblade-chronicles-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenoblade-chronicles-2)

[image]

Comment: I was expecting somebody to post a submission for XBC2, and you pulled through :)

Comment: If the WiiU could do screenshots, I'd have thrown up something from Xenoblade Chronicles X.

Answer (score 4):

Calamity Ganon rising on a Blood Moon in [hyrule-warriors-age-of-calamity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyrule-warriors-age-of-calamity)

[image: calamity Ganon]