# Screenshot of the Week Contest #37

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15718) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15804)*

---

Welcome to the thirty-seventh edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [n00dles' submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15726) of a giant larva from outer space in [no-mans-sky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-mans-sky) took the top spot with 12 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-04-26, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-05-03, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme

There is no theme this week, so go ahead and submit the best you have!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: I wonder if ants call moss "trees"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image: The Outer Worlds]

It took about 20 hours of gameplay for me to realize that the planets of [the-outer-worlds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-outer-worlds) are surprisingly breathtaking when they're not trying to kill you.

<sub>This is Terra 2, Emerald Vale Region, by the marker for the "All Halcyon in a Day" quest.</sub>

<sub>Yes, there's a severed arm on the rocks. We call that "ambience".</sub>

Comment: Amazing. Outer Worlds is a lot of fun, I must jump back in and try to finish it soon.

Comment: Definitely recommend. My biggest gripe is that it's not as big a world as other games like fallout 4 or assassin's creed odyssey/origins. :(

Comment: I took hundreds of shots in that game. The Asteroid-looking planet is cool too. The game ended a bit quick for my liking though. And I felt like it could have been bigger and more to do.

Comment: Yeah there was so much potential there. It ended up feeling really small -- the asteroid, sure that made sense it was a small exploration area, but otherwise there should have been whole _planets_ to explore.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Buildings in Satisfactory]

On overlooking view of my new start-up in Update 4 of [satisfactory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satisfactory)

Answer (score 8):

Bit of a *wildcard* this week...

[image]

This is a shot of the Sanctuary bridge in [fallout-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-4) taken while messing around with [console commands](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Fallout_4_console_commands). I think all I did here was remove the sky but it gives a nice *Film noir* look.

Comment: I think technically you removed the background. Once I managed to remove the settlement boundary, so as long as I stayed in build mode I could build and scrap _anywhere_. Never did manage to figure out what I deleted to make that possible though.

Comment: As long as you stayed in build mode? That's weird lol. I think I used `ToggleSky`(`ts`). I only use PC version to test my mods. I play on PS4 Pro.

Comment: looks like Limbo

Comment: This is what happens to your eyes when you drink the radioactive water from that very river :)

Answer (score 7):

With the new airship map in [among-us](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/among-us) there are numerous new tasks, including "Make Burger" in the kitchen. But sometimes the recipes are a bit ... unusual.

[image: A "Burger"]

At least it is healthy!

Comment: Hopefully with that much onion on their breath you'll be able to smell the imposter sneaking up on you... ;)

Answer (score 6):

The first arrival on Giant's Deep is always a jaw-dropping experience for new players.  [outer-wilds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outer-wilds)

[image: First Arrival on Giant's Deep]

Answer (score 4):

Today was [Cross the Pond Westbound](https://ctp.vatsim.net/), a VATSIM event featuring transatlantic flight and I was lucky enough to get a slot this year, flying Amsterdam Airport Schiphol to Boston Logan International, about a 7 hour flight in a 777-200LR.

UNFORTUNATELY, [x-plane-11](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-plane-11) crashed as Boston Approach was giving me vectors for final approach, so I don't have anything from my view landing, so please accept instead this drone view of Boston after I signed back in on the ground for a screenshot.

[image: A busy arrival day in Boston]

Comment: The detail level is amazing. You recommend this one or MFS for a new player?

Comment: If the game crashes, does your plane continue on? Wonder if there was some catastrophic crash event that you missed :D

Comment: @Kaizerwolf No, xPilot disconnected me from the network as soon as X-Plane closed, so I simply ceased to exist on the controller's radar screen.

Comment: @LoreFriendly I would say that the MSFS probably has better overall detail, but X-Plane has the advantage of having been around for a while so it supports a lot of freeware and payware add-ons, like this very good freeware Boston Airport scenery add-on (and the payware Boeing 777 I flew the whole way).

Answer (score 4):

Playing some [left-4-dead-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/left-4-dead-2) with friends. Guess who had to sacrifice themself in the name of achievements?

[image: Kill Bill]

Comment: Reminds me of Domination in COD, I'm always the one running straight into the DOM point, sacrificing K/D ratio for the team to win. While the sniper hiding in some corner picking off random enemies gets a higher K/D and gets the top spot.