# Screenshot of the Week Contest #38: Into the Storm

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15753) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15837)*

---

Welcome to the thirty-eighth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Roddy of the Frozen Peas' submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15754) of Aurora Borealis on Terra 2 in [the-outer-worlds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-outer-worlds) took the top spot with 14 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-05-10, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-05-17, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme

The theme for this week is **Into the Storm**. You can interpret this how you wish, whether that means a huge thunderstorm, or an electrical storm out in space. Send us the best you've got!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Sam Porter Bridges* on his way towards the supercell in [death-stranding](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-stranding).

[image: Death Stranding - Supercell]

Answer (score 11):

A storm approaches in [sea-of-thieves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-of-thieves)
[image]

Answer (score 7):

*Kerbal Space Program*, doing Elkano Challenge - circumnavigating Duna in a [yellow trucky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4X86.jpg) from the VAB floor. About to enter a dust storm in one of Duna's basins.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[Come Hell and High Water](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gASby.jpg): Ready to brave the hurricane in [left-4-dead-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/left-4-dead-2)'s Hard Rain campaign.

[image: Leaving the safe house in Left 4 Dead 2]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Bandit Fort in Horizon Zero Dawn]

Scouting a Bandit Fort in [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn)