# Screenshot of the Week Contest #39

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15804) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15851)*

---

Good morning and welcome to the thirty-ninth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [DefaultSimon's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15807) of the supercell in [death-stranding](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-stranding) took the top spot with 14 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-05-24, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-05-31, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme

There is no theme for this week, so go ahead and submit whatever you want!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Phineas' Lab with *The Hope*, orbiting above Terra 2 in [the-outer-worlds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-outer-worlds)

[image: The Hope]

Comment: Still waiting for this game to go on more than 50% off LOL

Comment: I got it at half price at this last steam winter sale. Still waiting for the dlc's to go on sale again though. ;) Honestly in retrospect I would go for it in the 20-40% off range. Nice shot, Robotnik!

Answer (score 10):

[image: No Man's Sky Base]

My Main Base in [no-mans-sky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-mans-sky)

Comment: Ugh. Everyone's base looks better than mine. >_<

Comment: I love the building oportunities in this game (it has some weird behaviour like other base-buildable games has, but I kind of expect those now :\) You can see the start of my latest build at the end of [my money-making video](https://youtu.be/Wt-6PyVD5FU?t=232) (yup, 27 views! xD) My stairs go all the way up the column!

Answer (score 5):

Ready to fight some monsters in [resident-evil-0](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-0)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

'Pursuing Scrotus'.  I know it looks like a promo image, but it was captured during the final encounter with the in-game screenshot tool.  Unfortunately I did not make a version without the logo overlay.

Captured in [mad-max](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mad-max) on PS4

[image: Pursuing Scrotus]