# Screenshot of the Week Contest #40: Robots!

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15837) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15870)*

---

Good morning and welcome to the fortieth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Robotnik's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15843/8350) of Phineas' Lab in [the-outer-worlds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-outer-worlds) took the top spot with 13 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-06-07, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-06-14, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme

The theme for this week is Robots/Synths/AIs, as suggested by [Dragonrage](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15040/8350), so go ahead and show your appreciation for your robot overlords.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: Somebody better post a screenshot of Horizon: Zero Dawn :)

Comment: Are piloted mechs in line with the theme? I would imagine not. They are robots, but not synths/AI

Comment: @BoogaRoo, by the same token, pure AIs are probably also out. Sorry Cortana

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Monkey versus Dog in [enslaved-odyssey-to-the-west](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enslaved-odyssey-to-the-west)

[image: Dog mech from Enslaved: Odyssey to the West]

Answer (score 9):

> "*My name is Legion, for we are many*".

The first encounter with the geth "mobile platform" in [mass-effect-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-2), another memorable Bioware character:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

BD-1 helps to take down an ancient droid in [star-wars-jedi-fallen-order](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-jedi-fallen-order).

[image: BD-1 helps with ancient droid]

(Since the theme is "Robots" I decided to play it safe and tried to take a screenshot with at least 2 robots)

Answer (score 5):

My [Summoner Mech](https://www.sarna.net/wiki/Summoner_(Thor)) in [mechwarrior-2-31st-century-combat](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechwarrior-2-31st-century-combat).  I still think this game to this day has some of the best sound effects.

[image: Mech]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Storm Briner in The Legend of Heroes: Trails in the Sky SC]

Both Man and Machine feel the sting of Scherazard's Whip in [trails-in-the-sky-sc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trails-in-the-sky-sc)