# Screenshot of the Week Contest #41

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15851) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15905)*

---

Hello and welcome to the forty-first edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Booga Roo's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15861) of a the player facing off against a Dog mech in [enslaved-odyssey-to-the-west](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enslaved-odyssey-to-the-west) took the top spot with 11 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-06-21, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-06-28, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme

There is no theme this week, so go ahead and submit the best you have!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Enjoying time travel in [portal-reloaded](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portal-reloaded)

Answer (score 9):

My Archipelago Adventures park in [parkitect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parkitect).

[image: Archipelago Adventures in Parkitect]

Comment: The best part about these SOTW challenges is discovering new games that I didn't even know about. As a die-hard RCT and Planet Coaster fan, this looks right up my alley.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Parkitect is great. I only picked it up last week, and I already put over 20 hours into. It feels like a proper Rollercoaster Tycoon 2 sequel. It shares many of the same mechanics from those first 2 RCT games, and improves upon it in several ways. The management side of things is significantly better than Planet Coaster from what I've heard, which is great, since the poor management sim aspect is why I never picked up Planet Coaster.

Answer (score 9):

[image: NMS Pet]

<sub>(... I was going  to wait until we had a pets themed challenge, but couldn't resist.)</sub>

My newly hatched animal companion, affectionately named "Lil Buddy", in [no-mans-sky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-mans-sky). His daddy was so tall I didn't even come up to his knee, and this little guy will one day be even taller.

In case you *really* need it spelled out, that's me on the left. ;-)

Comment: Lil Buddy's secret power is that he -- and his rider -- [can walk through walls](https://imgur.com/a/KT8G5DZ). He's also immune to fall damage which is great when you're ambling through the void between caverns.

Comment: As someone who has brought up more than a few companions, I can appreciate how nice lil buddy is. It is quite difficult to fine one you really like. BTW, does he knock you off cliffs? My giant companion did! You'd hear boom, boom, BOOM behind you then you're flying through the air lol.

Comment: Actually no, he just runs headfirst off of them and then we continue wherever we land, sometimes going through the chasm walls. I don't think I've been sent flying like that since Prisms got released, but maybe i'm just lucky.

Answer (score 9):

**"Cong Dong - The Hero"**

[image: 'Cong Dong - The Hero' screenshot]

This is the screenshot from my latest giant map build in Far Cry Arcade in [far-cry-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/far-cry-5).
It's a small, Vietnam-War-era VC/NVA village, made of wood, on stilts, over a swamp. It's a stealthy nightmare!
(*'Cong Dong'* roughly means *'Closed Gate'*)

Comment: Whoa, this seems very cool.  What's the map building like in this game?

Comment: There are lots of good points and some bad points too. **Good:** Environment, memory, atmosphere, size and ease of use. **Bad:** AI is quite primative, lacks any logical tools like timers, counters etc and anything to create decent objectives (the built-in scripts are extremely limited and you can't link scripts in any way, plus only one script can be run at a time). So really your only solo objective options are: a kill list, a destroy list, survival, or just _get to the exit_. **TL;DR:** So it falls short on the scripting side, but does pretty well on the environment side.

Answer (score 6):

[image: DC-6 Flight Deck]

> Kennedy Ground, Clipper 985, aircraft type Douglas DC-6, request pushback and startup

I got a shiny new toy in [microsoft-flight-simulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-flight-simulator) and boy am I glad they programmed an AI Flight Engineer to help me monitor all these dials.

Comment: If that's the case can you at least PICK A CHAIR?!

Comment: @Joachim There's actually a flight engineer's seat modeled right where my camera is

Comment: Ah! And can you be joined by two AI's?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I've just stolen my Artificial Flight Engineer's chair. But, the "normal" airliner sim experience is in 2 crew aircraft with 1 person, so he helps keep this 3 crew ship afloat

Answer (score 6):

Frontier town nestled in the rock hills on Monarch - [the-outer-worlds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-outer-worlds)

[image: Monarch Outer Worlds]

Comment: _How have I not found this place yet omg_

Comment: @Roddy it's just outside Stellar bay. The township with the... interesting family who invite you to dinner

Comment: Fascinating. I remember that... family. Clearly you found an angle/vantage point that I've not found yet. Time to go climbing!

Comment: If you leave that family's residence by way of the upstairs balcony, you can jump + forward dodge over to a nearby balcony on the next building over, that's where I got this screenshot :-)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Things could have gone better, in [human-fall-flat](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-fall-flat)

Answer (score 4):

The newest Remedy game [control](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control) [is free on Epic](https://www.epicgames.com/store/en-US/p/control) until tomorrow 17/06 15.00 GMT.
I had been looking forward to it. Apart from the fascinating narrative - inspired once again by Twin Peaks, mythology, film noir, and 'the pulps' - the dynamic destruction is as impressive and fun as it was in Max Payne at that time.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Ludger and Milla Link Art in Tales of Xillia 2]

Teaming up with the Lord of Spirits, Milla Maxwell, in [tales-of-xillia-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tales-of-xillia-2)