# Screenshot of the Week Contest #42: Destruction!

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15870) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15929)*

---

Hello and welcome to the forty-second edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Wipqozn's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2Eng.jpg) [submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15872/8350) of his Archipelago Adventures park in [parkitect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parkitect) took the top spot with 12 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-07-05, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-07-12, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme

This weeks theme is Destruction!, as [suggested by Gnomeslice](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15326/8350). Images of the highest level of carnage, debris, or otherwise broken and explodey stuff.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: Dang it, you already meme'd it up.

Comment: My entries to [#7](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14946/171580) and [#20](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15280/171580) might qualify for this. Is it creation, is it destruction? Maybe lots of both? Who knows…

Answer (score 13):

[image]

Stopping time to admire explosions in [titanfall-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titanfall-2)

Comment: Starting off this week with a bang I see. Nice screenshot.

Comment: Protocol 3: Protect the Pilot

Comment: i loved this entire campaign but this mission sits with me still, best use of the time-stopping/controlling gimmick in games to date

Comment: This is a beautiful screenshot :D

Answer (score 9):

Exact moment after the bullet from my sniper rifle hit the grenade on this poor soldier's hip:

[image: Explosion]

[sniper-elite-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sniper-elite-4)

Answer (score 7):

How about a *precursor* to destruction in [sea-of-thieves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-of-thieves)?
[image]

Comment: Sadly I have to imagine the aftermath now. Bet it was warm :)

Comment: You should keep those in the Crow's Nest, like [this](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2308161408)

Comment: With normal kegs, I do. With stronghold kegs, on a sloop, it really doesn't make a difference :P

Answer (score 5):

Ladies and gentlemen, I auto-summoned my modified creeper mobs in
[minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition). Using a command block, they are being summoned at a rate of one creeper per 5 ticks in-game.

When I light one's fuse, and it explodes, the rest begin a chain reaction, and this is the result:

[image: Creeper explosion aftermath.]

It's the simple things in life.

Answer (score 5):

My ride out of this planet was just blown up by huge ancient alien cannon, looks like I will have to build my own ship out of scraps. [subnautica](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subnautica)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Rebel Galaxy]

Taking out some Doublejack Pirates in [rebel-galaxy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebel-galaxy)