# Screenshot of the Week Contest #43

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15905) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15962)*

---

Hello and welcome to the forty-third edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Batophobia's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15906) of an explosion frozen in time in [titanfall-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titanfall-2) took the top spot with 14 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-07-19, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-07-26, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme

There is no theme this week, so go ahead and submit the best you have!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Admiring the windows in [bug-fables](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug-fables)

Answer (score 11):

[image: A screenshot taken from the fan made game BladeRunner 9732, while played in Virtual Reality. The screenshot is taken from the balcony, outside of the apartment of Rick Deckard. The city outside is dark, mostly illuminated by artificial neon lights, vehicles and giant advertising TVs; one of the advertising TV is displaying the word "Enjoy" in white on a red background. It's raining outside, and you have an empty glass of whisky on the edge of the balcony, at the bottom of the screenshot.]

Enjoying the view outside, on the balcony of Rick Deckard's apartment, in Virtual Reality.

A fan-made game named BladeRunner 9732, in which you can just explore and interact with the apartment.

Comment: I love this! Gives a nice feel of that amazing retro-futuristic city. (Plus, I didn't know people make stuff like this). So cool.

Answer (score 11):

Geralt's way of dealing with adverse precipitation:

[image]

[the-witcher-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-3)

Comment: *summons bipedal horse*

Comment: Horse racing would be so much funnier...

Comment: Why the downvote? You know it doesn't make any difference, right?

Comment: There actually are people downvoting? Sigh.

Comment: His horse (Roach) is pretty badass. Reminds me of the [card they made for Roach in the Gwent game](https://cdn-l-mkt.cdprojektred.com/image/NEU_Roach_4_fin.png). Most developers won't even acknowledge their own bugs - while CD Projekt Red makes fine art representing them :)

Comment: @Amarth Oh, I've never seen that one, cool! Yeah, CPR is a gem :)

Comment: @Joachim (That is, [this gwent](https://www.playgwent.com/en) not the mini-game in Witcher 3)

Answer (score 8):

[image]

This tree has seen things [kirby-star-allies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kirby-star-allies)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

A holefish having some trouble behaving like a... well, fish.

Thanks [subnautica-below-zero](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subnautica-below-zero)