# Screenshot of the Week Contest #44 - RNG

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15929) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16007)*

---

Hello and welcome to the forty-fourth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Joachim's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15936) of a weird looking horse in [the-witcher-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-3) took the top spot with 13 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-08-02, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-08-09, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme - RNG

The theme for this week is **RNG**, so go ahead and submit some of your rarest drops, or perhaps your most unlucky moments in gaming.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: From unlucky encounters to rare drops, everybody prays to RNGesus

Comment: Really cool theme. Can't wait to see what people come up with.

Comment: It seems RNG screenshots need a lot of context and are not particularly exciting to see.

Answer (score 15):

RNGesus giveth, and RNGesus taketh away in [path-of-exile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-of-exile)

[image]

Context: That robe is a rare and very useful drop. Unfortunately the boss that dropped it is in an area that resets when you die, and he managed to kill me after he died and dropped the robe.

Answer (score 4):

So, I was just clearing bank space today on my ironman in [oldschool-runescape](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oldschool-runescape) opening some Wintertodt crates and...

[image: Unionhawk gets a new pet]

At only a 1/5,000 drop from a supply crate, it's [not the wildest RNG I've gotten on this account](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15137/20306), but it was very funny to get caught off guard like this. I literally did not notice this was my phoenix until I walked away from the bank chest.

Comment: wave1: Gzzzzzzz

Answer (score 3):

Won the cool million "lions" daily login reward in [war-thunder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/war-thunder).
[image]

Answer (score -2):

[image: Minecraft pond with shaders enabled]

Comment: You submitted your post after the submission period has ended. We’re currently in the voting period

Comment: The new SOTW of the week is now active, if you'd like to resubmit this photo, you can do so [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16007/screenshot-of-the-week-contest-45). Make sure you include a description of your photo, including what game it's from (Minecraft, I think?).

Comment: Yep! Thank you!