# Screenshot of the Week Contest #45

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15962) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16054)*

---

Hello and welcome to the forty-fifth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [SaintWacko's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15966/8350) of RNG giving him great loot only to immediately kill him in [path-of-exile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-of-exile) took the lead with 14 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-08-16, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-08-23, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme

There is no theme this week, so go ahead and submit the best you have!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 20):

Unwinding just outside [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn)'s [Sunfall](https://horizon.fandom.com/wiki/Sunfall), looking over hoodoos and dunes as the day rolls into a vibrant evening.

[image: Taking a nap outside Sunfall]

Comment: peep that tallneck in the background!

Comment: Another reason why I love HZD, the game is so beautiful.

Comment: There sure has been quite a few entries among the various screenshot of the weeks that this game was apart of!

Comment: @TimmyJim Makes sense when the game really only has graphics going for it.

Comment: @Wrigglenite I guess you didn't like it? I never played it so I have no opinions

Comment: @TimmyJim Couldn't really keep me interested, I wouldn't recommend it. I could go on a long rant but there's hardly space enough for that here.

Answer (score 10):

Ah, the irony in [kerbal-space-program](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kerbal-space-program)'s loading screen...

[image: Not really flying safe...]

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Minecraft forest with shaders ( What a shame they aren't on ps4 :/ )

Answer (score 7):

Say hello to Betsy [dungeon-defenders-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeon-defenders-2)

[image]

Comment: Coming in strong already. +1

Answer (score 6):

[image]

[assassins-creed-syndicate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-syndicate)

No Evie, that's not how you play Cricket!

Comment: Heh never saw this in all my time playing Syndicate. Where was this taken?

Comment: @LoreFriendly i believe i took the screenshot somewhere in the park that's infront of Buckingham Palace but it's not the only place as i had found people playing cricket a couple of times, generally in park areas or clean looking grassy areas with a couple of trees

Answer (score 5):

[might-and-magic-heroes-7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-heroes-7) has some unusual combat backgrounds!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

John Marston in [red-dead-redemption-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-dead-redemption-2) recreating the cover art to [red-dead-redemption](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-dead-redemption) during the epilogue:

[image: John Marston]

<sub>For reference, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePFcF.jpg) is the Read Dead Redemption cover art.</sub>

I had a big smile on my face during this cutscene because I knew what Rockstar pulled off here. If you haven't played these games, do it - and play them in order, you'll be happy that you did!

Answer (score 3):

Vibin' with Ariana Grande and other players during the Rift Tour in [fortnite](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fortnite):

[image: Screenshot of the Rift Tour in Fortnite.]

Comment: You play Fortnite @Taco タコス? I play all the time!

Comment: @MikeZ. I do :D

Comment: when did you start?

Comment: @MikeZ. earlier this year (April to May)

Comment: I started in the beginning of this chapter.

Answer (score 3):

Double kill with the Trench Gun in [call-of-duty-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-2)

[image]

Comment: People are still playing this?

Comment: @TimmyJim Showing my age a bit I guess. Thanks to pandemic lockdown my friends and I have been playing multiplayer games, CoD2 was a staple of our highschool experience so we set up a server. Managed to pull 10 of us together one night. Absolute chaos! :-)

Comment: Sounds like the good ole days. I loved COD World at War back in the day. I think I got to 8th prestige in multiplayer