# Screenshot of the Week #46: Character Customization!

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16007) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065)*

---

Hello and welcome to the forty-sixth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [DefaultSimon's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16018/8350) of a beautiful sunsut in [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn) took the lead with 21 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-08-30, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-09-06, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme - Character Customization

This weeks theme is **Character Customization!** Show us all those characters you've either spent hours (days?) creating in the character creation screen, or playing dress up with to make them the most stylish characters of all (Note: Characters which are horrifying and lacking in fashion sense are also welcome).

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: That awkward moment when the Mod team is so lazy that @Joachim needs to update the SOTW meta for us.

Comment: But it makes me feel so wonderfully indispensable :)

Answer (score 17):

[dark-souls-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls-3)

There was this serious cut scene at the end of the first DLC where your character will dramatically look back at some yet unknown threat. This scene doesn't look that serious when you are some funny mustache guy.

[image]

Comment: Not even gonna lie, I saw the tension before I scrolled down. It was gone the moment I saw his face. Totally get it 

Comment: Reminds me of the Super Mario 64 home screen where you could stretch Mario's face by pinching it.

Answer (score 11):

My carefully curated firebird ensemble in [world-of-warcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-warcraft)

[image]

[Bonus of the mount my ensemble matches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DZoP.jpg)

Comment: The bonus picture 

Answer (score 6):

After nearly two months of grinding to find alien artifacts in [fortnite](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fortnite), I've unlocked enough pieces to complete a *decent* looking Kymera character. Not quite where I want to be yet, but, it looks wise and agile, so that's a win to me.

[image: Screenshot of my customized Kymera character in Fortnite.]

Probably not the best with sniper rifles though.

Answer (score 6):

I made my Minecraft skin in such a way that it included as many iconic textures as I could fit:

[image]

There's TNT (kind of looks like a face, that's why I moved it to the front of the head), command block, bedrock, cobblestone, cut red sandstone (which has a wither texture), grass block, diamond ore, piston, ender pearl, enderman/dragon eyes, crafting table, redstone and at the side of the torso (not visible here) even very squished versions of Steve and a creeper.

Someone once called it an eldritch being with many eyes and now I cannot see unsee that. It does indeed include nine eye-like things and hints at six more.

As requested, here are some in-game screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jV3H.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6utV.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY1ZJ.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty2Mu.png
(Not embedded, because the image I'm submitting is just the first one.)

Comment: Huh? The embedded image and the comments are gone. Weird.

Answer (score 6):

Full achievement diary gear 4 [oldschool-runescape](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oldschool-runescape)

[image]